# Recursive call in lambda (C++11)

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, type-inference, auto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursive lambda functions in c++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c0x)

Why can't I call a lambda recursively if I write it as:

```
auto a = [&]
{ 
   static int i = 0; i++;
   std::cout << i << std::endl; 
   if (i<10) 
     a(); //recursive call
};
```

It gives compilation error ([ideone](http://www.ideone.com/rvQkt)):

```
prog.cpp:8:18: error: '((const main()::<lambda()>*)this)->main()::<lambda()>::a' cannot be used as a function

prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:9:9: error: variable 'auto a' with 'auto' type used in its own initializer
```

What does the error mean?

I understand the reason why I can't write this:

```
auto i=i+1; //error: unable to deduce 'auto' from '<expression error>'
```

We can't write this because the type of `i` has to be deduced from it's initialization, which means the type cannot be deduced if `i` itself appears in the initialization ([ideone](http://www.ideone.com/me0Oz)). But how does it matter in case of lambda? If I'm not wrong, the type of a lambda is determined by it's parameter(s) and the return type; it doesn't depend on the body if it returns nothing (in which case, the return type is deduced as `void`, irrespective of other statements in the lambda-body).

Anyway, I got a workaround, and I can use `std::function` instead as:

```
std::function<void()> a = [&] 
{ 
   static int i = 0; i++;
   std::cout << i << std::endl; 
   if (i<10) 
      a();
};
```

which compile fines ([ideone](http://www.ideone.com/5XK1B)). But I'm still interested to know the reason why the `auto` version doesn't compile.

Comment: I think the problem is related to you ending up with an implicit capture of `a`, as a reference which would recurse infinitely because `a` itself ends up as a member of `a`.

Comment: @awoodland: What does that mean? Please elaborate on that.

Comment: The type of the lambda also depends on the captures, which I suspect is the issue here.  If you don't use `a` then the compiler doesn't care, but when you do it doesn't know what type of object to use.

Comment: The theoretical CS textbook way to recursive lambdas is passing the function to itself as a parameter.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: I didn't understand this part of your comment >> `but when you do it doesn't know what type of object to use.` Why does it know then?

Comment: I don't think that the type of a lambda expression needs to depend on its parameters, return type or its captures. Recall that a lambda expression's type is just a class type. `struct internal_lambda_object0;` is the type `internal_lambda_object0` independent of what member functions or data members it has.

Comment: @Johannes: please, put a `__` in that name somewhere ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is that there is no special case for lambda-expression initializers of `auto` variables.

Such special cases would be prone to errors and misuses. You need to define the rules when you propose that something like `a()` should work. How is the `operator()` looked up? What is the precise state of `a`'s type? Will the type be complete? (which implies that you already know the capture list of the lambda). Once you have formulated that in a format reasonable for a spec, it would be easier to make statements on it.

Allowing your use case would mean yet another case where you need to scan ahead in code, because to determine the type of `a` in `a()` you must be sure that the initializer ends with nothing that could "unlambda" the type

```
struct y { void operator()() { } };
template<typename T> y operator+(T, y) { return y(); }
auto x = [] { x(); } + y();
```

In this case, `x()` would call `y::operator()`, not the lambda.

As it is now, `a` is simply forbidden to be mentioned in its entire initializer. Because in C++, `auto` is *not* a type. It is merely a type *specifier* standing for a to-be-deduced type. As a consequence, an expression can never have type *auto*.

Comment: "If you capture a by reference, then you will call a danging reference once you copy your lambda and the original a goes out of scope." - of course, all capture-by-reference is prone to this error/misuse, so I doubt that it motivates the committee in not providing a special case to allow `auto a` here to be captured by reference.

Comment: Together with the problem of capturing `a`, another reason that it's not possible to recursively call the closure is that there is otherwise no way to refer to that closure object: `this` designates the enclosing class object, if any.

Answer (score 6):

As I see it the important difference between the `auto a` case and the `std::function<void()> a` case is that the type `std::function<void()>` doesn't know/care about what the type of the real function it refers to really is. Writing:

```
std::function<void()> a;
```

is perfectly fine, where as:

```
auto a;
```

makes little sense. So when the time comes to synthesize the capture if you use `std::function<void()>` all that needs to be known about the type is already known, whereas with `auto` it's not yet known.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, and that if you were able to know the name of the lambda type generated by the compiler (which you cannot), then you could use that name in the decl instead of `auto`.  However, I could easily see this being in the "undefined behavior" category.

Comment: @MichaelPrice - I did try to dig out the quote on "you can never know the name of the type of a lambda" for this answer but I can't remember which section it was in.

Answer (score 2):

In a recursive function `f` is defined by `f` and return type of `f` is also determined by `f` in case of `auto` so it leads to infinite recursion.

when `auto` tries to derive a type. decltype(f()) will further deduce to another decltype(f)` as f derives to f e.g. a call on anything recursive is recursive too. return type determination turns recursive when applied on a recursive function. in a recursive function end of the recursion may be done on runtime. but determination is static only

Comment: @Neel: This doesn't make sense to me. When there is no return statement in the body, how can it return anything? Are you implying that `deep recursive level` means that lambda-body is infinitely large that it can't know the existence or non-existence of return statement(s)?

Comment: @awoodland: Thanks, I'vent looked at the comments yet. 
@Nawaz: In every function there exist a mathematical possibility to return something syntactic scanning for `return` syntax for visualization only.

Comment: +1 for picture appropriateness

Comment: @Neel: I still didn't understand it. Anyway, what I mean is that the recursive call doesn't increase or decrease the possibility of return statement(s). Return statement(s) can be statically determined. (By the way, I didn't downvote your answer).

Comment: assume `determineReturnType(f)` determines return type of `f` so `determineReturnType(f)` will further derive to determineReturnType(f)` as `f` derives to `f` e.g. a call on anything recursive is recursive too. return type determination turns recursive when applied on a recursive function. in a recursive function end of the recursion may be done on runtime. but determination is static only.

Comment: A mathematical analysis of the function is unnecessary here... the C++ language has very explicit rules about deducing return types, and one of them is that if there is no `return` statement the result is `void`.  What else happens in the function is immaterial.