# Can lambda functions be recursive?

Tags: c++, recursion, c++11, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursive lambda functions in c++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c0x)

Here is a plain old recursive function:

```
int fak(int n)
{
    return (n <= 1) ? 1 : n * fak(n - 1);
}
```

How would I write such a recursive function as a lambda function?

```
[](int n) { return (n <= 1) ? 1 : n * operator()(n - 1); }
// error: operator() not defined

[](int n) { return (n <= 1) ? 1 : n * (*this)(n - 1); }
// error: this wasn't captured for this lambda function
```

Is there any expression that denotes the current lambda so it can call itself recursively?

Comment: possible with huge std::function overhead or with polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, Great link you have there.

Comment: Oops - I accidentally deleted my comment.  here's the link back: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/11/18/stupid-lambda-tricks.aspx

Comment: @MichaelBurr, It's funny. I find the notion that you accidentally deleted your comment laughable, but I can relate to how easy it is to do something like that :p

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this here http://www.slideshare.net/adankevich/c11-15621074   29 slide

Comment: Why not just Y-combinator? http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#C.2B.2B

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Yes, they can. Starting with C++23 you can use the explicit this parameter:

```
auto factorial = [](this auto self, int i) 
{ 
    return (i == 1) ? 1 : i * self(i - 1); 
};
```

With previous C++ standards, you can store the lambda in a variable and reference that variable (although you cannot declare the type of that variable as `auto`, you would have to use an `std::function` object instead). For instance:

```
std::function<int (int)> factorial = [&] (int i) 
{ 
    return (i == 1) ? 1 : i * factorial(i - 1); 
};
```

Comment: I _think_ `factorial` needs to be captured by reference, but I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: @ildjarn you're right, otherwise you get a segfault.

Comment: Also note that such a function cannot be returned safely.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Good point, it would capture by reference a local object that is gone out of scope. You could still use a `shared_ptr` I guess (?), but that would be probably kind of fetish.

Comment: Would this work if factorial has state? Wouldn't copies of the function break?

Comment: a slightly more performant call would be a method that delegates implementation to a lambda that call again that method, It will avoid the overhead of a `std::function`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, hi can you please explain why in not unsafely?

Comment: @rikimaru2013 returning it destroys the local variable, and the function has a reference to that local variable.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes my bad, i see it now, thank u!

Comment: @rikimaru2013 also, just for completeness, note that the equivalent code using a dedicated struct type instead of a lambda would support that by the use of `this`.

Comment: Hmm, why can't `auto` be used for the lambda's type? I'd expect this to be possible as long as I specify return type for the lambda body. Silly C++ :(

Comment: This way you lose one of the features of lambdas: anonymity. You can't pass such an object inline like e.g. `applyMyLambda([](int x){__call_self(x-1);});`

Comment: in the std::function way I had thought you couldn't do this as a one-liner. Isn't the one-liner the equivalent of doing it with `auto` and a lambda? I thought you had to define the `std::function` variable first and let it be default initialized and then *assign* a lambda to it that captures the now fully defined variable by reference.