# Capturing breaks my lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a function getTotal:

```
int getTotal( const HitMap& hitMap, bool( *accept)(int chan) )
```

where the second argument is a bool function specifying which members of the container hitMap should be added to the total.

I'm trying to call it with a lambda. This works:

```
auto boxresult =
getTotal(piHits, [](int pmt)->bool
{ return (pmt/100) == 1;} );
```

but this doesn't:

```
int sector = 100;
auto boxresult =
getTotal(piHits, [sector](int pmt)->bool
{ return (pmt/sector) == 1;} );
```

I get the error

```
cannot convert ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>’ to ‘bool (*)(int)’
for argument ‘2’ to ‘int getTotal(const HitMap&, bool (*)(int))’
```

from my compiler (GCC 4.6.3). I tried `[&sector]` and `[=sector]` but it didn't make any difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Only non-capturing lambdas can be converted to a function *pointer*. Period.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When a lambda has a capture clause it can no longer be treated as a function pointer. To correct, use `std::function<bool(int)>` as the argument type for `getTotal()`:

```
int getTotal( const HitMap& hitMap, std::function<bool(int)> accept)
```

Comment: Thanks `template <typenameF > int getTotal( const HitMap& hitMap,F accept )` works. Do you have a link where I can read about why it's different with function pointers?

Comment: Oh, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7852154/1527126) makes sense.

Comment: @paco_uk: The reason is that when your lambda doesn't capture any data, to call it, the computer only needs to know where the code is stored. This means that a function pointer can be used to point to the code. When your lambda does capture data, it needs to know where the code is stored, and also to know what the data values are. This can't all be stored in a function pointer, so a functor is created behind the scenes, and that functor has a different type, because it stores different data.

Comment: @KenBloom thanks - that's even clearer!

Comment: There is a proposal for the next standard that would allow to bind stateful functions to function pointers. You can take a look [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3574.html).

Comment: @GermánDiago: that proposal requires write access to executable memory, which is not going to work on many systems

Answer (score 3):

The lambda function with capturing is not what you expect, you can use these ways:

```
template <typename F>
int getTotal( const HitMap& hitMap, F accept )
{

}
```

or

```
int getTotal( const HitMap& hitMap, std::function<bool(int)> accept )
{

}
```

The template based `getTotal` has better performance. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15409133/952747).