# It is possible to use T::operator< as default parameter for template function?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++17

I wonder if it is possible to use `operator<` or some other as default parameter of some function.

Some <del>stupid</del> **trivial** example:

```
template <typename T>
void compare(std::function<bool(T, T)> lessThan = T::operator<);
```

I try to do this thing for `int` as `T`, but of course I get an error:

```
error: ‘operator<’ is not a member of ‘int’
```

I really don't know if it is possible till `operator<` as I know isn't a static function.

**Do you have any idea, if and how it can be done?**

Any help will be apreciated! :)

Comment: you can use `std::less<T>{}` - or `std::less<>{}` if you have C++14 - as a default argument instead.

Comment: Also don't name a predicate that can do whatever `lessThan` and [don't use `std::function` as the parameter type here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409133/stdfunction-instead-of-templates-for-predicates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost always a bad idea to use `std::function` with template arguments in a template function.

`std::function` is type erasure, and template arguments are type deduction.  Type erasure and type deduction are **opposites** of each other.  Doing both is like building a house only to blow it up and build another one.

```
template <class T, class C=std::less<T>>
void compare(C&& c = {});
```

If you want to replace the compartor you can do

```
compare<int>( some_other_comparator );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this warning :) I completely forgot about `std::less` function. I know that there is `std::greater` also, but what if I want use some other operator like **bitwise and** as default parameter? Is there any convention for `operator` functions?

Comment: @BartekPL You can always write your own function object.  But `std::bit_and<T>` exists.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thank you once again ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always mimic what the standard library does.

```
template<typename T,typename C=std::less<T>>
void compare()
{
  C comparator{};
  //Your logic here
}
```

This way you don't have to instantiate the predicate before passing it to the `compare function`.
However you now have to call the `compare` function in the following way

```
compare<YourType>();
```

And if you need to change the predicate used by the `compare` function you call it like this

```
compare<YourType,NewComparator<>>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for a satisfying solution for a similar problem, but I managed to work it out using function pointers and lambda function.

```
template <typename T>
void compare(bool (*const lessThan)(const T&, const T&) = [](const T& a, const T& b){return a<b;});
```

You have the ability to pass your own function to compare() or to leave it out and stick with the a<b.