# Evaluating another class's dynamic function pointer without templating

Tags: c++, function-pointers, templating, dynamic-function

I have a class which interpolates a 2D function automatically (quite happy with it).  It accepts a dynamic function pointer to the method being interpolated.  I have had to template out the class, since I need the object instance as well as the pointer.

Can I avoid templating the class out?  Or will I need to keep doing so in order to accept the object instance as a parameter?  Is a base class possible? (I'm fairly new to c++)

The way I have it is (abbreviated):

```
template<class F>
class Interpolate {
   Interpolate(double (F::*f)(double, double), F & obj, ...) { 
      ...
      double value = (object.*f)(x,y);
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: You could use `std::function<double(double, double)>` and `std::bind`, but that's more expensive than what you have.

Comment: You can also bind to abstract interfaces (methods to call are pure virtual) and fix the template parameter to that particular interface.

Comment: How much more expensive would std::function<double(double, double)> be?  And, when would it be expensive, first use, or each use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, you can also use std::function. This give you more flexibility with std::bind. On the other hand, std::function may allocate the resulting function on the heap and this causes a big overhead (which may be avoid by using std::cref() ). A very interesting discussion about the differences in execution time of std::function vs templates can be found at [std::function vs template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677997/stdfunction-vs-template/15015502#15015502).

" Notice that std::function is able to store different types of callable objects. Hence, it must perform some type-erasure magic for the storage. Generally, this implies a dynamic memory allocation (by default through a call to new). It's well known that this is a quite costly operation. " by Cassio Neri - Here is where std::cref can help, specially because in the example discussed in the link I just wrote, without std::cref, the heap allocation of std::function slowed down the program by a factor 10!

Comment: Interesting, seems I get to choose between compile time and run time?

Comment: Not necessarily. With small functions, compiler may optimize the allocation ("The standard (20.8.11.2.1/5) encorages implementations to avoid the dynamic memory allocation for small objects which, thankfully, VS2012 does") and with larger functions, std::cref diminish the overhead considerably. It won't be as fast as templates (which is usually the rule - template solution is the fastest approach because work is done at compile time). This should be only critical if std::function wrap fast exec. functions and is called many many times (+- similar to virtual function overhead issue)

Comment: How about with GCC (running in linux) when the class is loading windows DLLs for evaluation?  The functions themselves are relatively expensive, so I'm trying to get a feel for where I would suffer the performance.  On construction only would be fine - on eval, no.

Comment: Good Question. It should be easy to check. But one of the main point of that link is that if you don't pass the function by reference (using std::ref or std::cref), then the std::function overhead will be big even for expensive functions. That is a warning that I see few people being aware of.