# Type of lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying to learn lambdas in C++, but stumbled on something I can't quite understand.

Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef double Func(double); 

double applyFunc(Func f, double x)
{
    return f(x);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << applyFunc([](double x) {return x + 1;}, 3) << std::endl;
}
```

Now this works just fine (prints "4"), i.e. type of the lambda expression used is exactly `double (*)(double)`.

But if I add closure to the lambda expression, like:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    std::cout << applyFunc([n](double x) {return x + n;}, 3) << std::endl;
}
```

Then I get an error from the compiler:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: cannot convert ‘main()::__lambda0’ to ‘double (*)(double)’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘double applyFunc(double (*)(double), double)’
  3) << std::endl;
   ^
```

And I don't understand why is that. I mean, from the point of view of `applyFunc()` it still receives a pointer to a function taking `double` argument and returning `double`, and it doesn't know that we used variable 'n' from context, so the type of lambda expression should be the same, as in the first example, right?

I would very appreciate help, thank you in advance!

Comment: std::function<double (double)> could be an optional solution.

Comment: A pointer to a function can't possibly store `n`.

Comment: The compiler error told you that lambda functions could not be converted to function pointers. All your need is to convert it to a std::function object.

Comment: No need for `std::function` here. Deduce a template parameter that represents any callable type.

Comment: @chris; Ahh I didn't know that. I thought he was having trouble with the function pointer signature..

Comment: @Brandon, I can't blame you. Using explicit function pointer types instead of function types for parameters is much more common. Not sure why the same isn't true of "arrays".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda is convertable to a function pointer only if it does not have a capture, we can see this by going to the draft standard section `5.1.2` *Lambda expressions* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> The closure type for a lambda-expression **with no lambda-capture** has a
>   public non-virtual non-explicit const **conversion function to pointer
>   to function** having the same parameter and return types as the closure
>   type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion
>   function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has
>   the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

This is an alternative solution which does not rely on this conversion:

```
template <typename Callable>
double applyFunc(Callable f, double x)
{
    return f(x);
}
```

**Update**

If you are interested in the difference between using `std::function` and templates then you should read [std::function vs template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14677997/1708801). There are many good answers there and a lot of food for thought.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, as I understand, there are two ways of defining the type of input parameter as a function: deducing type from template or using std::function. Both are working and giving same results. I wonder, in what situation I would **have** to use std::function ?

Comment: @Ganil I updated my answer with a link to an excellent question that covers this, I could not possibly do justice to the answers with a summary.

Answer (score 2):

Each lambda expression returns an object with a distinct type. If the lambda expression does *not* capture any variables, it can be converted to a a function pointer type of an appropriate signature (i.e., the return type and the arguments need to agree with those of the lambda expression). When there is a variable captured, the entity created can't be represented by a plain function. Instead, the lambda expression yields an object of class type with a function call operator. That is, your second code uses a lambda expression yielding an object of a class which is roughly equivalent to this:

```
class lambda {
     int n;
public:
     lambda(int n): n(n) {}
     double operator()(double x) const { return x + n; }
};
```