# Which way of invoking lambdas in C++ is the most idiomatic?

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

I noticed that lambdas both work using function pointers as well as the dedicated `function` type using `g++`.

```
#include <functional>

typedef int(*fptr)(int, int);

int apply_p(fptr f, int a, int b) {
  return f(a, b);
}

int apply_f(std::function<int(int, int)> f, int a, int b) {
  return f(a, b);
}

void example() {
  auto add = [](int a, int b) -> int {
    return a + b;
  };

  apply_p(add, 2, 3); // doesn't give an error like I'd expect it to
  apply_f(add, 2, 3); 
}
```

My question is: Which of these are most idiomatic to use? And what are the dangers and/or benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: Related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26748736/1708801) asked today. The conversion to function pointer only works if the lambda has no capture. As my answer there is another alternative using a template and treating the lambda as a Callable. `std::function` incurs overhead and it can not be optimized away like a lambda can.

Comment: The second version may incur an unnecessary overhead. I would make `apply_f` a function template instead.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour wow.. random timing

Comment: what @juanchopanza says is imo the best advice: not having to care about function pointer syntax, no performance overhead of std::function and it works with everything you throw at it which matches the call - including 'raw' functions, std::functions, lambdas, your own operator classes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I noticed that lambdas both work using function pointers as well as the dedicated `function` type

If the lambda doesn't capture anything, then it can decay to a function pointer.

> Which of these are most idiomatic to use?

Neither. Use `function` if you want to store an arbitrary callable object. If you just want to create and use one, keep it generic:

```
template <typename Function>
int apply(Function && f, int a, int b) {
     return f(a,b);
}
```

You can go further and make the return and argument type(s) generic; I'll leave that as an exercise.

> And what are the dangers and/or benefits of using one over the other?

The function pointer version only works with (non-member or static) functions and non-capturing lambdas, and doesn't allow any state to be passed; only the function itself and its arguments. The `function` type can wrap any callable object type, with or without state, so is more generally useful. However, this has a run-time cost: to hide the wrapped type, calling it will involve a virtual function call (or similar); and it may need dynamic memory allocation to hold a large type.

Comment: isn't it dangerous to keep it _that_ generic? doesn't it completely lose all type-safety doing this?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: I don't see any danger, and it certainly doesn't lose *all* type safety. It allows any type for which `f(a,b)` is a well-formed expression convertible to `int` to be used. Other types will be rejected.

Answer (score 4):

I would say (C++14)

```
template <class Functor, class... Args>
decltype(auto) apply_functor(Functor&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return std::forward<Functor>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

or C++11:

```
template <class Functor, class... Args>
auto apply_functor(Functor&& f, Args&&... args) ->decltype(std::forward<Functor>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    return std::forward<Functor>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: You could consider making it `std::forward<Functor>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` to preserve the value category of the `f` argument as well.

Comment: @Niall thanks, fixed. Also changed `auto` to `decltype(auto)` for C++14 version to support returning by reference.

Answer (score 2):

If in doubt, prefer `std::function`:

1. The syntax is much more straightforward and consistent with other types, consider e.g.

   ```
   typedef std::function<int (int, int)> MyAddFunction;
   ```

   and

   ```
   typedef int (*MyAddFunction)( int, int );
   ```
2. It's more generic (it actually can take a lambda or a plain C function or a functor)
3. It's more type safe

   ```
   apply_p(0, 0, 0); // probably crashes at runtime, dereferences null pointer
   apply_f(0, 0, 0); // doesn't even compile
   ```

Comment: What are `apply_f` and `apply_p`?

Comment: @AdriC.S. The functions defined in the question.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes, but I meant which one: is `apply_f` is the function and `apply_p` is the pointer?

Comment: @AdriC.S.: Yes, that's how they're defined in the question.

Comment: @AdriC.S. Thanks for your comment, they made me realize I actually mixed them up -- _`apply_p`_ would crash when invokd with a `0`. :-) I suppose that's why my answer was -1'ed ?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Thanks to you for your answer! I'm glad I was of some use :D