# C++ passing function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have the following function

```
static void p (){

}
```

I want to pass a function pointer to p into function x.

```
void x(void * ptr){

}
```

I am trying the following, and it is not working.

```
...
x(ptr);
```

Note x and p are in different classes.
I am getting the following compiling error.

```
invalid conversion from 'void (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: `void *` is for DATA pointers, not function pointers! They may not even be the same size.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i< oo; i++) this.answer("same");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
void x(void(*function)())
{
  // Whatever...
}
```

If you're using C++11 you can [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
void x(std::function<void()> function)
{
  // Whatever
}
```

Comment: `std::function` should be reserved for storing type-erased functionoids. For parameter passing, templates are preferred.

Comment: @Quentin - do you have a citation for why that's the case?

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677997/stdfunction-vs-template) cover it. `std::function` is a type-erased object, and this comes at the price of indirection and dynamic allocation, since nothing is known about the pointee. Passing any functionoid with its type perfectly deduced by a template parameter can be completely inlined and optimized.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at the error message:

> invalid conversion from `'void (*)()'` to `'void*'` [-fpermissive]

It means that `void*` (a **data pointer**) is the type specified in `x`,
but `void (*)()` (a **function pointer**) is being passed instead.

So change `x` to

```
void x(void (*ptr)())
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error message. `void*` is not a pointer to function, `void(*)()` (for example) is. You should rewrite `x` as follows :

```
void x(void (*ptr)()) {

}
```

A pointer-to-function is written this way :

```
Ret (*name)(Params)
```

Where

- `Ret` is the pointee's return type
- `name` is the name of the pointer
- `Params` is the list ofthe pointee's parameters, as you would write them in its declaration.

Example :

```
double (*ptr)(int, float)
```

...can point to a function taking an `int` and a `float` and returning a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

`void*` is not a function pointer, it's a void pointer.

To declare a function pointer, use `void (*ptr)()`.

Comment: using "void (*ptr) ()" did not work, had to use "void (*ptr)" as suggested by @Sean

Comment: @DisplayName101 I don't understand. @Sean suggests `void (*)()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

We can do some ugly pointer magic, like this:

```
static void function1( char* c ) {
    printf( "%s", c );
}

void function2( void* ptr ) {
    void(* func)(char*) = (void(*)(char*))ptr;
    func( "a" );
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    void* f = function1;
    function2( f );
    return 0;
}
```

This is bad, but it works in such situations.