# Passing lambda to template function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I have the following code:

```
template <typename L>
double measure( L&& action )
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point start, end;
    duration<double> timeSpan;

    start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    action();
    end = high_resolution_clock::now();

    timeSpan = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
    return timeSpan.count();
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
    cout << measure([](){ mergeSort<float>(array, 0, 10000); }) << endl << endl;
```

And so far, this is the only way I know to pass lambda functions. BUT, I was trying to make this function more complete, allowing to pass a ratio<> as template argument, to specify the ratio<> of the timeSpan template, to return time in other measure than milliseconds...

So, I want to know how can I pass multiple template arguments to a function and pass a lambda together. What should I specify on the template as the lambda's type or, what else can I do to achieve something like this:

```
    timer::measure<ratio<1,1000>>([](){ mergeSort<float>(array, 0, 10000); })
```

?

Comment: How would the template argument `std::ratio<1, 1000>` be used inside `measure` exactly?

Comment: second last line of function would be `timeSpan = duration_cast<duration<double, RATIO>>(end - start);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just have something like this:

```
template <typename Ratio, typename L>
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
double measure( L&& action )
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    action();
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto timeSpan = duration_cast<duration<double, Ratio>>(end - start);
    //                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return timeSpan.count();
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7201ceffbfa59bde)

Comment: g++ gives me a long error output when I've tried this. Tried again just to check if I typed something wrong, but no. g++ basically complains this: `note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:`

Comment: @PedroVernetti [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f8bbe8a1116b843). That sounds like an error [that would happen](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f429852574e23240) if you forgot to update your call to `measure` with `measure<ratio<1,1000>>`.

Comment: No. Really not the case. I've typed exactly as I proposed.

Comment: @PedroVernetti Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) regarding this error?

Comment: While shortening the code to show you, I've realized there was a missing '>' in the `duration_cast< ...` I'm sorry. When you said I may have forget to update the call, I only checked the call..

Answer (score -4):

First of all, the standard way to pass lambda functions is to use `std:function`:

```
#include <functional>

...

double measure( std::function<void()> action ){
    ...
}
```

Then use it in the same way you use

```
cout << measure([&](){ mergeSort<float>(array, 0, 10000); }) << endl << endl;
```

Then, you can apply Jefffrey's answer with removal of template parameter `L`.

Comment: The "standard" i.e. recommended way to _store_ lambda functions is `std::function`. In contrast, when **passing**, using a function template on the receiving side is superior, because doing so avoids the added overhead of `std::function`... which itself is a template _anyway, **but**_ with a pile of added bloat to enable type-erasure, which in this case isn't required. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677997