# Prettiest way to iterate all values of an unsigned integer

Tags: c++, c++11, iteration

I want to iterate all possible values of an integer. This code does not work as the termination condition never becomes false:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= 0xFFFFFFFF; i++)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

I've come up with this:

```
auto loopBody = [](uint32_t value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
};

uint32_t last = 0xFFFFFFFF;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < last; i++)
    loopBody(i);

loopBody(last);
```

It is fairly ugly, though. Is there a prettier way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could use an `int64_t` index and loop to `0x100000000`?

Comment: Use `std::numeric_limits<your_type>::max()`. Note that overflow of signed integers is undefined behavior.

Comment: "prettiness" is arbitrary. I think just having the loop and then an extra std::cout statement is cleaner than defining a function to do it. If it bugs you that much, maybe use zneak's suggestion of using a larger datatype that won't overflow. Then if you ever need to loop through the larger datatype you'll have the same problem.

Comment: amazing this question has so few upvotes. only 4 including mine, after 5 years.  there must be a dupe somewhere with more common search terms.

@zneak - that approach works if you have int64_t's available. in general I think it would be best to use an approach which does not require a wider data-type than the iteratand (?) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check for the break condition in the loop header, since for that you would need to exclude the maximum value.

Instead, do the check in the loop body and leave the check in the header empty:

```
for (auto i = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest(); ; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    if (i == std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
        break;
}
```

With a do-while loop, you don't need to check inside the loop body, but you need to move the counter variable to the outer scope, and if you want to avoid undefined behavior, you can only use unsigned integer types:

```
auto i = std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::lowest();
do {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
} while (i++ < std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max());
```

Note that the `i++` will overflow, but that only happens *after* acquiring the current value (we're using postfix increment.) With signed integers however, this overflow would be undefined behavior, and even though we're not using the value after the overflow occurs, undefined behavior can have unpredictable results, even *before* it actually occurred.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was looking for: check has to happen after I execute loop body, not before. Great!

Comment: Reinventing a `do{}whie()` since 2016.

Comment: @NikosC still need to do the check? How so?

Comment: @NikosC That's not how a do-while loop works. Try running one.

Comment: Missing post-increment?

Comment: @n.m. Actually, I take that back. You are right. :-P It can be done.

Comment: The original question was about unsigned, but you went with signed. I missed that, sorry. Yes, for signed int overflow is UB, so you can't do that, but for unsigned it works.

Comment: You can write a bit more complicated condition for `while` to avoid an overflow, but at this point I don't think it's really worth it.

Comment: @n.m. I've put the working do-while version in the answer.  I'm not a language lawyer, but I think it works because even though you overflow, you are not using the value. You're using the value **before** it overflows, and thus before UB occurred, so it should be fine, I think.

Comment: The problem here is that id UB occurs, anything can happen, including incorrect results *before* the UB (this is known as "time travel" and is known to actually happen with current compilers). I'd change the type to unsigned in that example

Answer (score 5):

I would use something like this:

```
uint32_t i = 0;
do
{
    // Your code here.
    i++;
}
while (i != 0);
```

I personally find it more elegant than a solution involving `std::numeric_limits`.

---

As @NicosC said, keep in mind that you should not do same trick with *signed* integers, because signed overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that this is UB with signed integers. But it's fine with unsigned.

Comment: super minor but personally i'd go with `while (++i != 0)` on the tail there, instead of incrementing `i` inside the loop.  altho you do need to be sure that `++i` gets used instead of `i++`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it call for condition test at the end of the loop, which means using `do {} while()`

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto beg = std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::lowest();
    auto end = std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max();

    std::cout << beg << " " << end << std::endl;

    long long count = 0LL;

    auto i = beg;
    do {
        ++count;
        if ((count % (1024LL*1024LL)) == 0)
            std::cout << count << std::endl;
    } while(i++ != end);
    std::cout << count << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `std::numeric_limits` as it states your intent best.

```
int lowest = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();
int max    = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
for (int i = lowest; i < max; ++i)
   cout << i << '\n';
cout << max << '\n';
```

or in a function see this [Demo](https://ideone.com/WG1gh7)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <functional>

template <class T>
void for_all(std::function<void(T)> fn)
{
    T lowest = std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest();
    T max    = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    for (T i{lowest}; i < max; ++i)
       fn(i);
    fn(max);
}

int main()
{
    for_all<int>([](int i) { 
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Edit: I edited the comparison

Edit 2: See comments. Props to kec ;-)

Comment: This results is semi-equivalent generated code as my first code example, which results in an infinite loop. That code is broken.

Comment: For signed types, this invokes undefined behavior. But just change it to `<`, and add one more increment.

Comment: True. Shall I delete the answer?

Comment: I think it's okay now. May want to add that it will never actually print the maximum value, but that it can be added as another print after the loop.

Comment: No need to use an inefficient `std::function`.

Comment: What is the proper way to wrap a function. Template?

Comment: Ok, thanks for that comment. I learned alot by searching for the [difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677997/stdfunction-vs-template)