# How to restrict template functor return and parameter types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

My code looks like this:

```
template<typename F>
void printHello(F f)
{
    f("Hello!");
}

int main() {
    std::string buf;
    printHello([&buf](const char*msg) { buf += msg; });
    printHello([&buf]() { });
}
```

The question is - how can I restrict the `F` type to accept only lambdas that have a signature `void(const char*)`, so that the second call to `printHello` doesn't fail at some obscure place inside `printHello` but instead on the line that calls `printHello` incorrectly?

**==EDIT==**

I *know* that `std::function` can solve it in this particular case (is what I'd use if I really wanted to print 'hello'). But `std::function` is really something else and comes at a cost (however small that cost is, as of today, April 2016, GCC and MSVC *cannot* optimize away the virtual call). So my question can be seen as purely academic - is there a "template" way to solve it?

Comment: `auto printHello(F f) -> decltype(f(""), void())`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Although the error is not necessarily less obscure.

Comment: You could also use `<functional>` instead of a template... `void printHello(std::function<void(const char*)> f)`

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use `std::function` for [performance reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677997/stdfunction-vs-template).

Answer (score 5):

unless you're using an ancient standard library, `std::function` will have optimisations for small function objects (of which yours is one). You will see no performance reduction whatsoever.

People who tell you not to use `std::function` because of performance reasons are the very same people who 'optimise' code before measuring performance bottlenecks.

Write the code that expresses intent. *IF* it becomes a performance bottleneck (it won't) then look at changing it.

I once worked on a financial forwards pricing system. Someone decided that it ran too slowly (64 cores, multiple server boxes, hundreds of thousands of discrete algorithms running in parallel in a massive DAG). So we profiled it.

What did we find?

The processing took almost no time at all. The program spent 99% of its time converting doubles to strings and strings to doubles at the boundaries of the IO, where we had to communicate with a message bus.

Using a lambda in place of a `std::function` for the callbacks would have made no difference whatsoever.

Write elegant code. Express your intent clearly. Compile with optimisations. Marvel as the compiler does its job and turns your 100 lines of c++ into 5 machine code instructions.

A simple demonstration:

```
#include <functional>

// external function forces an actual function call
extern void other_func(const char* p);

// try to force std::function to call polymorphically    
void test_it(const std::function<void(const char*)>& f, const char* p)
{
    f(p);
}

int main()
{
    // make our function object
    auto f = std::function<void(const char*)>([](const char* p) { other_func(p); });

    const char* const data[] = {
        "foo",
        "bar",
        "baz"
    };

    // call it in a tight loop
    for(auto p : data) {
        test_it(f, p);
    }
}
```

compile with apple clang, -O2:

result:

```
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
Lfunc_begin1:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 155, ___gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 16, Lexception1
## BB#0:                                ## %_ZNKSt3__18functionIFvPKcEEclES2_.exit.i

#
# the normal stack frame stuff...
#
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp13:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp14:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp15:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    pushq   %r15
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $72, %rsp
Ltmp16:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -40
Ltmp17:
    .cfi_offset %r14, -32
Ltmp18:
    .cfi_offset %r15, -24
    movq    ___stack_chk_guard@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rbx
    movq    (%rbx), %rbx
    movq    %rbx, -32(%rbp)
    leaq    -80(%rbp), %r15
    movq    %r15, -48(%rbp)
#
# take the address of std::function's vtable... we'll need it (once)
#
    leaq    __ZTVNSt3__110__function6__funcIZ4mainE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS2_EEFvPKcEEE+16(%rip), %rax
#
# here's the tight loop...
#
    movq    %rax, -80(%rbp)
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movq    %rdi, -88(%rbp)
Ltmp3:
#
# oh look! std::function's call has been TOTALLY INLINED!!
#
    callq   __Z10other_funcPKc
Ltmp4:
LBB1_2:                                 ## %_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZ4mainE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS2_EEFvPKcEEclEOS6_.exit
                                        ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
#
# notice that the loop itself uses more instructions than the call??
#

    leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -88(%rbp)
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    je  LBB1_1
## BB#3:                                ## %_ZNKSt3__18functionIFvPKcEEclES2_.exit.i.1
                                        ##   in Loop: Header=BB1_2 Depth=1
#
# destructor called once (constant time, therefore irrelevant)
#
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movq    48(%rax), %rax
Ltmp5:
    leaq    -88(%rbp), %rsi
    callq   *%rax
Ltmp6:
## BB#4:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB1_2 Depth=1
    leaq    L_.str2(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -88(%rbp)
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    jne LBB1_5
#
# the rest of this function is exception handling. Executed at most 
# once, in exceptional circumstances. Therefore, irrelevant.
#
LBB1_1:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB1_2 Depth=1
    movl    $8, %edi
    callq   ___cxa_allocate_exception
    movq    __ZTVNSt3__117bad_function_callE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
    addq    $16, %rcx
    movq    %rcx, (%rax)
Ltmp10:
    movq    __ZTINSt3__117bad_function_callE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    movq    __ZNSt3__117bad_function_callD1Ev@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   ___cxa_throw
Ltmp11:
    jmp LBB1_2
LBB1_9:                                 ## %.loopexit.split-lp
Ltmp12:
    jmp LBB1_10
LBB1_5:                                 ## %_ZNKSt3__18functionIFvPKcEEclES2_.exit.i.2
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movq    48(%rax), %rax
Ltmp7:
    leaq    -88(%rbp), %rsi
    callq   *%rax
Ltmp8:
## BB#6:
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
    cmpq    %r15, %rdi
    je  LBB1_7
## BB#15:
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    je  LBB1_17
## BB#16:
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    callq   *40(%rax)
    jmp LBB1_17
LBB1_7:
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rax
    leaq    -80(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   *32(%rax)
LBB1_17:                                ## %_ZNSt3__18functionIFvPKcEED1Ev.exit
    cmpq    -32(%rbp), %rbx
    jne LBB1_19
## BB#18:                               ## %_ZNSt3__18functionIFvPKcEED1Ev.exit
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $72, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    popq    %r15
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Can we stop arguing about performance now please?

Comment: The small functor optimization saves you an allocation, but it doesn't remove all of `std::function`'s costs.

Comment: @T.C. which are what, exactly? One extra load per function call (which can be reordered anyway)? If this function call is going to be at the epicentre of the tightest of tight loops then we can have a discussion about optimisation. Otherwise it's an utter waste of time. There'll be much lower hanging fruit elsewhere.

Comment: It messes with inlining.

Comment: @T.C. With the greatest respect, I'll say to you what I would say to any one of my development team who wanted to spend time optimising for performance, "please either show me measurements to prove that the user experience is suffering because of the extra memory fetch, or let's stop wasting time on conversations about efficiency and instead focus on provable correctness and adding the features that our users are asking us for." Without the measurements we don't even know whether the fetch happens, on account of there being a rather large cache on the chip.

Comment: The choice might be between a full function call vs. inline the one-line function body, but I do agree with most of the points you are making.

Comment: @T.C. I think we completely agree that there's a minor performance penalty (and having just compiled a test to assembly, the overhead is actually only the indirection through the virtual function table when calling the destructor - in this case the actual call through std::function gets inlined anyway). I think we also agree that it almost never matters. Maybe it would if you were making the call once per pixel in a software shader, In which case, sure, lets do something cleverer. But for almost every other application? There's nothing gained. This just won't be the bottleneck.

Comment: @RichardHodges, where's your sense of adventure? Clearly whatever device that buffer is written to will benefit greatly from the femtosecond of savings offered by 50 lines of inpenetrable template code!

Comment: I'm impressed. (GCC can't inline that call, as far as I can see; haven't checked MSVC.)

Comment: @T.C. GCC won't inline `main()`. Try moving the whole test to another function. I'd be stunned if a recent version of GCC/libstdc++ won't inline it.

Comment: Called it `meow()`. Nothing changed.

Comment: @T.C. sad face :( That's interesting. gcc is better than clang at inlining (even large) vectors. perhaps flag it as a missed optimisation opportunity on gcc's mailing list?

Comment: Your use and creation of that function was adjacent: but templates suffer same need in practice.  There should be one vtable load per lambda used, not per function object, but if doing a tight loop that overhead should be small (one cache miss, and as noted we know we need it long before we need it).  I am impressed at clang; I wonder if it was `final` that kicked it over to being able to inline `std::function`s?

Comment: One concern: the above uses a stateless lambda, placement constructed (known to do nada), a final vtable call to a trivial body that does not use `this`.  I could see using non-trivial construction *or* use of this *or* falling outside SFO could all *maybe* screw with inline.  Esp because the dtor should equally be inlined, but it was not, and it should never have loaded the vtable on a local final class.  I will admit that `std::function` overhead is basically ignorable outside of per-pixel per-frame type loops *even without inlining* (and that code is rare). (like, gigacalls/second).

Comment: @Yakk that's what I'm trying to convey - only people who know exactly why they care about the cost of std::function need to care. For almost every real use case it's irrelevant. But coders will be coders - ignoring the elephant in the room while they search for a nonexistent mouse :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add compile time checking for template parameters by defining constraints.

This'll allow to catch such errors early and you also won't have runtime overhead as no code is generated for a constraint using current compilers.

For example we can define such constraint:

```
template<class F, class T> struct CanCall 
{
  static void constraints(F f, T a) { f(a); }
  CanCall() { void(*p)(F, T) = constraints; }
};
```

CanCall checks (at compile time) that a F can be called with T.

Usage:

```
template<typename F>
void printHello(F f)
{
  CanCall<F, const char*>();

  f("Hello!");
}
```

As a result compilers also give readable error messages for a failed constraint.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not make it fail on the line that calls `printHello` incorrectly, but inside `CanCall`.

Answer (score 1):

Well... Just use SFINAE

```
template<typename T>
auto printHello(T f) -> void_t<decltype(f(std::declval<const char*>()))> {
    f("hello");
}
```

And `void_t` is implemented as:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

The return type will act as a constraint on parameter sent to your function. If the expression inside the `decltype` cannot be evaluated, it will result in an error.

Comment: Can be done without a helper template: `auto printHello(T f) -> decltype(f(std::declval<const char*>()), void())`. The terms before the comma are evaluated but are otherwise ignored, that holds even inside `decltype`.