# Best practice for implementing an interface-like pure abstract base class in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to declare a pure abstract base class with a virtual destructor. I know three ways to do this, but I do not know which is best, or why.

My goal is to implement abstract base class interfaces in best-practice C++11 style, with optimal runtime performance. In particular, I would like to afford inlining/elimination of no-op destructors. I'd also like to eliminate warnings related to duplicate vtables, either by choosing an implementation that doesn't generate the duplicat vtables, or by making an informed decision to suppress the warnings.

Here are the three ways to implement an abstract base class that I know:

**Option #1**

```
/// A.h:

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual int f() = 0;
};
```

**Option #2**

```
/// A.h:

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A();
    virtual int f() = 0;
};

/// A.cpp:

A::~A() {}
```

**Option #3**

```
/// A.h:

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual int f() = 0;
};
```

Are these my only options?

Which of #1, #2, #3, is considered best practice? If there are trade-offs (e.g. runtime vs. compile time performance) please describe them.

With option #1, will the inline destructor ever be inlined?

I understand that option #1 will put a vtable into every translation unit. Option #1 generates the `-Wweak-vtables` warning in clang, and is covered by the "vague linkage" category in gcc[1]. Option #3 does not generate the clang warning -- does this mean that option #3 does not generate a vtable?

How exactly does option #3 differ from the other options?

Other questions have discussed similar issues with respect to clang's warnings, but I was unable to find a question that specifically addressed which option is considered best practice and why.

[1] https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html

Comment: The [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) has a good section about this type of question and might be worth it for you to read.

Comment: I do scientific computations and in my area none of these variants is used for polymorphism. For really performance-critical tasks take a look at [static polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) or the [Barton-Nackman-Trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick)

Comment: @Maikel yes, I use those techniques too. But this question is about the plain-old vtable-based polymorphism technique.

Comment: Then I am sorry, I just hoped to help. Well, the Core Guidelines propose to use variant C but I think it is not explained in the extent of detail you are asking for. :-(

Comment: @Maikel, no need to apologise, your comments are helpful :)

Comment: You actually/technically have a fourth option, although it won't help you much. In your option#2 in A.cpp you can do `A::~A() = default;` rather than `A::~A() {}`.

Answer (score 1):

best practice (at least when I'm in charge):

```
struct A {

    //
    // keep move semantics available - rule of 0, 3, or 5
    // in this case, 5 because we defined a destructor.
    //
    A(const A&) = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(const A&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
    virtual ~A() = default;

    // non-polymorphic interface in terms of private polymorphic
    // implementation

    int f() 
    try
    {
        // possibly lock a mutex here?
        // possibly some setup code, logging, bookkeeping?
        return f_impl();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        // log the nested exception hierarchy
        std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error(__func__));
    }   

private:

    virtual int f_impl() = 0;

};
```

> Why is it important in your opinion to have a try-catch block for f()? – einpoklum 16 mins ago

@einpoklum I'm glad you asked. Because if you do this in every method and every function, and throw a nested exception containing the function name (and any relevant arguments), it means that when you finally catch the exception, you can unwrap all the nested exceptions into your log file or cerr and you get a perfect stack trace pointing exactly at the problem.

reference for unwrapping nested exceptions:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested

> doesn't that hurt performance?

Not one little bit.

> But it's a pain to add a function try block to every function

It's a much bigger pain to have to try to reproduce a problem that you have no idea how or why it occurred, and no clue as to the context. Trust me on this...

Comment: Why is it important in your opinion to have a try-catch block for `f()`?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm glad you asked. Because if you do this in every method and every function, and throw a nested exception containing the function name (and any relevant arguments), it means that when you finally catch the exception, you can unwrap all the nested exceptions into your log file or cerr and you get a perfect stack trace pointing exactly at the problem.

Comment: You've explained the reason for preferring a nested exception over a plain exception. But why an exception at all? Nobody said f() would necessarily be throwing anything. Do you recommend having try-catch block in all virtual methods in the base class/mixin?

Comment: @einpoklum method f is not marked noexcept. Therefore we must assume that it can throw exceptions.

Comment: A significant part of the question concerns the definition of the destructor. Could you please clarify *why* you choose the `= default` destructor form, and why you are prepared to forgo vtable anchoring (assuming that you are).

Comment: @RossBencina always prefer a compiler generated destructor. If you use composition, you'll always be able to and you'll get easy move/copy/delete implementations.

Comment: @RossBencina vtable anchoring is an artificial non-requirement. The compiler will put the vtable into a common block. The linker will take care of it. Write elegant code, express intent. Don't try to do the compiler's job for it. You'll do a worse job. example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365852/how-to-restrict-template-functor-return-and-parameter-types/36366261#36366261

Comment: @RichardHodges Clang warns about lack of vtable anchoring: I take it you would disable this warning rather than place the dtor in a .cpp file.

Comment: @RichardHodges - just because the method is not marked noexcept does not mean it must be surrounded by try-catch IMO. Also, the exception thrown may/may not inherit from std::exception.

Comment: @RichardHodges This is very much opinionated. This kind of programming reminds me the days when we used to add error handling for every function that returned an error code because it was "good practice" to do so. In practice, that caused us to write more code that just made us hide the real errors and make other errors because of bad handling of the original error. Also, this does not answer the OP's question

Comment: @RossBencina if you have a platform-specific requirement, like exporting from a shared library, then you must do what is required. If the executable is monolithic (as I prefer mine to be for reasons of performance, reliability and ease of installation) then no anchoring is required.

Comment: @user1708860 as stated, the reason for catching and re-throwing a nested exception is for ease of finding the problem when you look at a log file or error report. The reason for using function try blocks is to completely separate this from the logic.