# In C++, is it possible to define a function with a varying code block to be executed and passed via another function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class handling SQL queries (it uses Qt functions, but I think this doesn't matter). All queries that write data have the exact same base frame that looks like this:

```
bool Database::someSqlFunction(some variables)
{
    if (! startTransaction()) {
        return false;
    }

    QSqlQuery query(m_db);

    try {
        ... Code using the passed variables and query ...
        commitTransaction();
    } catch (...) {
        rollbackTransaction(query);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is it possible to re-use this code so that it won't have to be defined per function? I thought about using a function to be called with a pointer to the function containing the varying code, but the signature is different for each function and I thus would have to define an overloaded one for each case; I also thought about using the preprocessor to generate the function, but it's the same problem with the different number and type of arguments.

Can a block of code to be executed be passed to another function? Or can this be done via a function template?

**Edit: Here's how this can be implemented:**

In the header:

```
template<typename SqlFunction>
bool writeHelper(SqlFunction sqlFunction)
{
    if (! startTransaction()) {
        return false;
    }

    QSqlQuery query(m_db);

    try {
        sqlFunction(query);
        commitTransaction();
    } catch (...) {
        rollbackTransaction(query);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And and example function using it:

```
bool Database::registerPlayers(const QString &name, int markerId)
{
    return writeHelper([&](QSqlQuery &query) {
        queryPrepare(query, QStringLiteral("INSERT INTO players(id, name, marker) "
                                           "VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)"));
        query.bindValue(0, name);
        query.bindValue(1, markerId != 0 ? markerId : SQLITE_NULL);
        queryExec(query);
    });
}
```

**Edit 2: The same can also be achieved without templates:**

Using `std::function`, the lambda defined in the actual function can simply be passed without having to use templates. The implementation of the helper function looks like this then:

```
bool Database::writeHelper(std::function<void(QSqlQuery &query)> sqlFunction)
{
    if (! startTransaction()) {
        return false;
    }

    QSqlQuery query(m_db);
    try {
        sqlFunction(query);
        commitTransaction();
    } catch (...) {
        rollbackTransaction(query);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Anyway, it's apparently better to use the template approach, as in this case, the compiler will generate the needed functions build-time and can optimize, whereas he doesn't know what will be actually done using the std::function approach, as the calls happen run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda closures seem to be what you need.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

As an example, generic algorithms are very similar to your use case: a common
algorithm which does not change and some small parts that
can be freely provided at the invocation.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm

Without knowing the exact details of what is expected,
I provide here a trivial example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Fnct>
void
common_part(Fnct fnct)
{
  std::cout << "begin common part\n";
  for(auto i=0; i<3; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "iteration " << i << " of common part\n";
    fnct(i);
  }
  std::cout << "end common part\n";
}

void
specific_function_A()
{
  common_part(
    [&](const auto &n)
    {
      std::cout << "specific part A: " << n << '\n';
    });
}

void
specific_function_B(int something_else)
{
  common_part(
    [&](const auto &n)
    {
      std::cout << "specific part B: " << n+something_else << '\n';
      something_else*=2;
    });
}

int
main()
{
  specific_function_A();
  std::cout << "~~~~~~~~\n";
  specific_function_B(100);
  return 0;
}
```

Even if the signature of the lambda-closure is always the same, the
capture can be seen as a workaround to provide additional parameters.

Comment: I use lambdas, but only to connect Qt signals to trivial functions … would I define someSqlFunction as a e. g. writeHelper and then pass a reference to a lambda function defined in the respective function that returns the return value of writeHelper? Would you mind to give an example?

Comment: Using std::function, there's no need for templates, see my edit above. Thanks anyway for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: @TobiasLeupold Yes it works too, but I have always heard/read that we should avoid using `std::function` as much as possible because it introduces some memory and performance overhead. Item 5 of *Effective modern C++* by Scott Meyers explains this.

Comment: @TobiasLeupold This question is interesting too https://stackoverflow.com/q/14677997/11527076

Comment: Oh, thanks about that info! I thought using std::function was the "easier" way, and I didn't think about speed.