# sigma function with any function input

Tags: c++, function, math, lambda

I have been making various functions that will compute the sigma in a range of very specific functions. I am now trying to write a sigma function that you would input a lambda or a function and it would then calculate the sum of its outputs within a range. I have the iteration code done fine but now need to figure out how to input a lambda and call it inside that function.
here is my current code:

```
int sigma(int start, int end, ? function) {
    if (start == end) {
        return function(start);
    }
    else {
        return function(start) + sigma(start + 1, end, function);
    }
}
```

PS if anyone could help me make this not use recursion that would be amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this function into a function-template:

```
template<typename Fn>
int sigma(int start, int end, Fn function) {
 // ...
}
```

and then call it with a lambda:

```
auto lam = [](int) { return 42; };

std::cout << sigma(1, 5, lam);
```

To avoid the rescursion, the body could simply be:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
  sum += function(i);

return sum;
```

Comment: thank you. this method was exactly what I needed for this. how would I make the input function return either a float or an int?

Comment: If you notice, nowhere is it specified what the function must return. So you could do that. However, withing `sigma`, you have to choose (at compile time), what type you want the input function to return.

Answer (score 0):

You need the type for your parameter. So ask yourself what is this parameter supposed to be? Based upon your definition of `sigma()`, you appear to be expecting a function-like object that is invoked with an `int` parameter and returns an `int`. That is, a [`std::function<int(int)>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Your function's declaration might end up looking like the following.

```
int sigma(int start, int end, std::function<int(int)> & function);
```

If you want to handle functions with other signatures, then a function template might be more appropriate. See [std::function vs template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677997/stdfunction-vs-template) for a discussion.