# What kind of design pattern to access encapsulating scope variables in a lambda function without changing the signature?

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

I am using a library for an optimizer (Brent's method) that has a function "local_min".

Its prototype is defined roughly as follows:

```
double local_min ( double f ( double x ) );
```

The function accepts a function pointer (?) as a parameter.  Suppose f(x) is the function... the optimizer will test various values for x to find a minimum value for f(x).

The local_min function is called such as:

```
double f(double x){
    return .5 + x * x;
}

int main(){
    double fx = local_min(f);
    return 0;
}
```

The trouble I am having is that I want to define the .5 as a scalar for the function, but I do not want to use global values.  Ideally, I would have everything in a single class.  But everything I try, I change the function signature of f(x) and it will no longer be accepted by local_min().

For example:

```
int main(){
    double value = 0.5;

    auto lambda = [](double x) {
        return value + x * x;
    };

    double fx = local_min(f);
    return 0;
}
```

does not work because *value* is not accessible.  Similarly,

```
int main(){
    double value = 0.5;

    auto lambda = [&](double x) {
        return value + x * x;
    };

    double fx = local_min(f);
    return 0;
}
```

changes the function signature and is no longer accepted by local_min().

Comment: Do you absolutely need `local_min` to accept a function pointer? That's perhaps a stricter requirement than you want/need. Is there a reason you don't want to use a template or `std::function`?

Comment: @Brian I have the source code, and can modify it to suit my purposes, but I would like to keep the resulting code as general as possible.

Comment: The most general approach would be to make `local_min` a template over the callable type. This related question discusses why using template is generally the preferred approach: [std::function vs template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677997/stdfunction-vs-template). Function pointers are best avoided in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a function pointer, make `local_min` accept an arbitrary type. This will let you pass it a lambda with captures as desired

```
template<typename F>
double local_min(F f) 
{
  // ... same usage as before
}
```

The callable `f` will still behave the same way as before, i.e. like a function that takes a `double` and returns a `double`. If you call `local_min` with an incompatible type, it will fail to compile. You can check for this with a `static_assert` to give the user a nice error message if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of capture by reference which requires the value to be available in the scope where the function it would be called. How about capture by value?

```
int main(){
    double value = 0.5;

    auto f = [value](double x) {
        return value + x * x;
    };

    double fx = local_min(f);
    return 0;
}
```