# Call C++ recursive lambda in the same line where it is declared

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, lambda

This is mostly a one liner style type of question, I would normally write this code in multiple lines anyway for readability reasons.

So my question is can I call the recursive lambda in the same statement where it is defined?

So instead of this:

```
int n=3;
function<void(int)> f {[n,&f](int i){if (i>1) { cout << "func(a, "; f(i-1); cout << ")";} else cout << "a";}};
f(n);
```

call the function with `n` in the same line where f is defined.

Comment: would you consider `function<void(int)> f;` `f = ...;` to have the *definition* on the second line?</weasel>

Comment: @jaggedSpire: That does not address the issue of actually calling the lambda with the initial input value.

Comment: Storing a lambda in a `std::function` is inefficient (constructs a function from the lambda) - better to store it in a  `auto` variable as that will capture the lambdas true type and not convert to `std::function`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau if you do that, though, you'll already have the symbol to bind to the lambda defined, and you can do `f = [f&](int){}, f(value);`

Comment: @JesperJuhl you need to have a function or else you can not have recursive function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531993/can-lambda-functions-be-recursive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me offer a glimpse into the functional programming world, where people usually use [combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) to deal with recursive lambdas. There was a [proposal (P0200r0)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0200r0.html) last year to add a simple Y-combinator to the standard library.

Leaving aside the question whether it is a good idea to do this, this would allow you to write and invoke a recursive lambda like this:

```
y_combinator([](auto self, int i){
    if (i>1) {
        std::cout << "func(a, ";
        self(i-1);
        std::cout << ")";
    } else {
        std::cout << "a";
    }
})(6);
```

The basic idea here is that the y-combinator is a higher order function that wraps a lambda which is passed 'itself' as a first argument. The combinator takes care of wrapping the self argument away for all invocations of the lambda.

You can [try it in coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/153cb62bad649ef9).

Comment: Awesome, we've been waiting this for years.

Comment: Also this answer although I accepted it has few upvotes. Spirit of Haskell Success is strong. :P

Answer (score 14):

In one statement which declares several variables ;-)
Mostly not what you want:

```
std::function<void(int)>
    f {[&f](int i){
        if (i>1) {
            std::cout << "func(a, "; f(i-1); std::cout << ")";}
        else
            std::cout << "a";
    }},
    dummy((f(3), nullptr));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58c4d900bbd2ca2c)

Comment: Someone perplexed asked about this answer here: [dummy() function - What is that supposed to be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805379/dummy-function-what-is-that-supposed-to-be)

Answer (score 6):

As a matter of fact, you can. Here is a complete example which compiles and runs fine with `g++ -std=c++11`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::function<int(int)> f = ([&f](int i){ return i?f(i-1)*i:1; }), trash = (std::cout << f(3) << std::endl, f);
}
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea to actually use this: The construct `, trash = (..., f)` would be in order for code golf or obfuscated programming contests, but would not meet my standards for production code.

Answer (score 3):

What you are essentially asking for is to create a temporary instance of `std::function` and then invoke `operator()` on that object in the same statement.  Both of these fail to compile for me with the same error when I try that:

```
function<void(int)> f{[&f](int i){ if (i > 1) { cout << "func(a, "; f(i-1); cout << ")"; } else cout << "a"; }}(n);
```

```
function<void(int)> f([&f](int i){ if (i > 1) { cout << "func(a, "; f(i-1); cout << ")"; } else cout << "a"; })(n);
```

> error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘(’ token

Pointing at the `(` of `(n)`.

See @Jarod42's answer for a viable workaround, if you don't mind the extra variable initialization.

Alternatively, this would work, though it does have to use separate variable declaration and assignment:

```
function<void(int)> f; f = [&f](int i){ if (i > 1) { cout << "func(a, "; f(i-1); cout << ")"; } else cout << "a"; }, f(n);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/EGI6S3)

Comment: not, really, it cant be a temporary since it is nameless and I need to capture so I can call it recursively.

Comment: You can't capture, let alone call, something that doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you consider it valid since it doesn't use lambda functions, but it is still single line and leaves no temporal variables behind ;)

```
struct {
  struct R {
    R(int i) {
      if (i>1) { cout << "func(a, "; R(i-1); cout << ")"; }
      else cout << "a";
    }
  } r;
} f{n};
```