# dummy() function - What is that supposed to be?

Tags: c++, c++11

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42796710/4711812) question here on SO and stumbled over the best voted answer, which used code like this to call a lambda recursively:

```
std::function<void(int)>
    f {[&f](int i){
        // do something
    }},
    dummy((f(3), nullptr));
```

I wondered what the `dummy(...)` part was about so I did some research but couldn't find anything about it. In the code snippet provided in the answer there was the `<utility>` header used so I guess that thing must be declared somewhere in there, but I still couldn't find anything about it.

Could someone explain what that `dummy` function (or functor) does, where it is declared and what it is usually used for?

I mean obviously in the example it is used to call the function f. But what its actual purpose?

NOTE: I know that question is a little broad, but since I couldn't find any information about it I could not focus the question onto one specif problem. Also I hope that an answer to my questions will help others finding information about the mysterious `dummy()`.

Comment: Note that the recursion in the original question only comes from the fact that where you have `// do something`, the original question actually invokes `f`. There's nothing "recursive" about `dummy`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Let's simplify the declaration a bit by using simpler types and expressions. We'll use `int` instead of `std::function<void(int)>`, `42` instead of the lambda, and `f += 1` instead of `f(3)`:

```
int f{42}, dummy((f += 1, 0));
```

To make it even more obvious, we can also use braces instead of parentheses for the second initialisation:

```
int f{42}, dummy{(f += 1, 0)};
```

This way, it should be clearer. It's a declaration which declares two variables: `f` and `dummy`. `f` is initialised with `42`, and `dummy` is initialised with this expression: `(f += 1, 0)`. That one's using the comma operator to first evaluate `f += 1`, discard the result, and then use the value `0` to initalise `dummy`.

Going back to the full (nonsimplified) declaration:

The type of both variables `f` and `dummy` is `std::function<void(int)>`. First `f` is initialised with a lambda. Then, `dummy` is initialised using a comma expression. The left-hand side of that expression, `f(3)`, is evaluated and forgotten. The right-hand side, `nullptr`, is then used to initialise `dummy`. Initialising a `std::function` with `nullptr` results in creating an empty `std::function` object (the same as a default-constructed one).

The whole purpose of `dummy` is to introduce some extra context on the same line (= in the same declaration) in which `f` could be invoked.

Answer (score 18):

> where [`dummy`] is declared

In the declaration that you show. Simplified:

```
T f /* the declarator */, dummy /* the declarator */;
```

`dummy` is just a name of a variable, just like `f`. They are both declared in the same declaration.

> Could someone explain what that dummy function (or functor) does
>
> I mean obviously in the example it is used to call the function f. But what its actual purpose?

That **is** the actual purpose. The only reason it is declared, is so that `f` could be called within the same declaration, as was desired in the linked question. The solution is silly, but so is perhaps the desire.