# Recursive std::function is throwing errors

Tags: c++

I was trying to use lambda function recursively as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> x = [](int y) -> int {
        if(y == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return y + x(--y);
        }
    };
    
    cout << x(3) << endl;
}
```

But it is throwing below errors.

```
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:20:24: error: ‘x’ is not captured
             return y + x(--y);
                        ^
main.cpp:16:34: note: the lambda has no capture-default
     std::function<int(int)> x = [](int y) -> int {
                                  ^
main.cpp:16:29: note: ‘std::function x’ declared here
     std::function<int(int)> x = [](int y) -> int {
                             ^
```

Is this throwing error because x is not fully defined when compiler reaches x(--y)? Can any one please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try capturing `x` as the error messages say?  `[&x](int y) -> int { /* ... */ }`

Comment: I would rather use a normal function for that. You are trying to capture something that is not declared already. Which is the lambda function it self.

Comment: See the "capturing variables" section of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627218/9716597

Comment: When I tried to capture as &x, it is giving the output as '3'. But it should give output as 6 (3 + 2 + 1).

Comment: @kadina Change `x(--y)` to `x(y-1)` to avoid unsequenced point issue.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Thanks a lot. It is working fine.  Can you please post this as answer. I will accept it.

Comment: *"Is this throwing error because x is not fully defined when [...]"* -- why would you come to this conclusion when the error message rather clearly identifies something else ("not captured") as the reason for the error?

Comment: Notice that your `std::function` is not really copyable afterward. One way to avoid that is "y-connector", `auto x = [](auto self, int y) -> int{ return y == 0 ? 0 : y + self(self, y - 1); }; std::cout << x(x, 3);` (as bonus, no-longer overhead with `std::function`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

This line looks suspcious:

```
return y + x(--y);
```

You're decrementing `y` and evaluating it within the same expression.  The rules vary between "defined" and "undefined" on statements like this.  But I suspect you really want this:

```
return y + x(y-1);
```

Split your declaration of `x` separate from the assignment. And capture `x` by reference:

```
int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> x;
    x = [&x](int y) -> int {
        if (y == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return y + x(y-1);
        }
    };

    cout << x(3) << endl;
}
```

The result is that `6` will get printed.

Comment: I tried this. Still I am getting output as 3.

Comment: I am following as per the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531993/can-lambda-functions-be-recursive. Still I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: oh I see the issue.... Change `y + x(--y)` to `y + x(y-1)`

Comment: `y + x(--y)` is undefined behaviour; the operands of `+` are not sequenced

Comment: *"Split your declaration of x separate from the assignment."*. No needs.