# How do I create a 'reference' to a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to capture a 'reference' to a lambda, and I thought that a function pointer would do the trick, as in:

```
int (*factorial)(int) = [&](int x){
    return (x < 2)
        ? 1
        : x * factorial(x - 1);
};
```

but I get `cannot convert from main::lambda<......> to int(_cdecl *)(int)`.

What's the proper way to point to a lambda then?

Comment: A lambda can be converted to a function pointer if it doesn't capture anything.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c0x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the lambda is not stateless, it cannot be converted to a function pointer. Use `std::function` instead.

```
std::function<int(int)> factorial  = [&](int x){
  return (x < 2)
      ? 1
      : x * factorial(x - 1);
};
```

Comment: This has non-trivial overhead costs, as a warning, compared to "raw" lambdas.  Each call is roughly equivalent to calling a `virtual` method.  It isn't that bad, but compared to the work being done in the call, is significant.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, you do pay the cost of `std::function`'s type erasure; I was just looking for that answer from a few weeks ago to link to :)

Comment: What does that mean `not stateless`? Also, @Yakk what are the overhead costs?

Comment: @sircodesalot A stateful lambda is a lambda that captures state.  Ie, if you have anything within the `[]` at the start of the lambda, your lambda has state.  I edited my answer with information about the overhead costs.

Comment: @sircodesalot Not stateless means it's capturing variables within its context. In this case, it is recursively referring to the `std::function` object `factorial`.

Comment: @Praetorian: I guess you were looking for [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9088690/1137388).

Answer (score 5):

This would be closest to what you have already:

```
std::function<int (int)> factorial = [&](int x){
    return (x < 2)
        ? 1
        : x * factorial(x - 1);
};
```

normally you could also use `auto`, but in this case it doesn't work because the function is recursive.

Answer (score 5):

You already have good answers. The following is just a curiosity but I wouldn't suggest you to use it.

As said by others answer, the lambda `factorial` tries to capture itself and hence it's not stateless. Therefore, it's not convertible to a function pointer.

Lambdas don't need to capture global or `static` objects, so if you make `factorial` a global or `static` variable then you don't need to capture it and this works fine (gcc 4.7.2)

```
    #include <iostream>

    typedef int (*function)(int);

    int main() {
        static function factorial = [](int x){
            return (x < 2) ? 1 : x * factorial(x - 1);
        };
        std::cout << factorial(5) << '\n';
    }
```

You can also create a factory like this:

```
    #include <iostream>

    typedef int (*function)(int);

    function make_factorial() {
        static function factorial = [](int x){
            return (x < 2) ? 1 : x * factorial(x - 1);
        };
        return factorial;
    }

    int main() {
        auto factorial = make_factorial();
        std::cout << factorial(5) << '\n';
    }
```

If you want to obfuscate even more :-) then eliminate the `typedef`:

```
    // This is a function returning a pointer to a function taking an int and returning an int.
    int (*(make_factorial)())(int) {
        static int (*factorial)(int) = [](int x){
            return (x < 2) ? 1 : x * factorial(x - 1);
        };
        return factorial;
    }
```