# Recursive lambda functions in C++14

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

There is an oft-repeated 'trick' to write recursive lambda functions in C++11 that goes as follows:

```
std::function<int(int)> factorial;
factorial = [&factorial](int n)
{ return n < 2 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1); };

assert( factorial(5) == 120 );
```

(e.g. [Recursive lambda functions in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067988/726300).)

This technique has two immediate drawbacks though: the target of the `std::function<Sig>` object is tied (via the capture by reference) to a very particular `std::function<Sig>` object (here, `factorial`). This means that the resulting functor typically cannot be returned from a function, or else the reference would be left dangling.

Another (although less immediate) problem is that the use of `std::function` is typically going to prevent compiler optimizations, a side-effect of the need for type-erasure in its implementation. This is not hypothetical and can easily be tested.

In the hypothetical situation where recursive lambda expressions would really be convenient, is there a way to address those issues?

Comment: Uhm... obviously not using a lambda expression is the natural option here...

Comment: Yep. Write a normal standalone C++ function ;)

Comment: @LucDanton: If you've chosen to write a recursive lambda in C++, you have chosen *poorly*. There's no reason to do that when you could just write a class inside your function. Yes, it'll be more tedious, but it'll still be easier than the gymnastics you'll need for recursive lambdas.

Comment: @LucDanton: Are they really? *Most* of it is in the support component, but the lambda needs to be written to work in that framework and you have to use it within a call to `fix`. Not saying that it is horrible or anything, but this looks as if lambda was the new *golden hammer* and this was adding a screwdriver tip to the handle...

Comment: @dyp that something would be [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dea903aa9363232)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The crux of the issue is that in a C++ lambda expression the *implicit* `this` parameter will always refer to the object of the enclosing context of the expression, if present at all, and not the functor object resulting from the lambda expression.

Borrowing a leaf from [anonymous recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_recursion) (sometimes also known as 'open recursion'), we can use the generic lambda expressions of C++14 to re-introduce an *explicit* parameter to refer to our would-be recursive functor:

```
auto f = [](auto&& self, int n) -> int
{ return n < 2 ? 1 : n * self(/* hold on */); };
```

The caller now has a new burden of making calls of the form e.g. `f(f, 5)`. Since our lambda expression is self-referential, it is in fact a caller of itself and thus we should have `return n < 2 ? 1 : n * self(self, n - 1);`.

Since that pattern of explicitly passing the functor object itself in the first position is predictable, we can refactor this ugly wart away:

```
template<typename Functor>
struct fix_type {
    Functor functor;

    template<typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const&
    { return functor(functor, std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

    /* other cv- and ref-qualified overloads of operator() omitted for brevity */
};

template<typename Functor>
fix_type<typename std::decay<Functor>::type> fix(Functor&& functor)
{ return { std::forward<Functor>(functor) }; }
```

This allows one to write:

```
auto factorial = fix([](auto&& self, int n) -> int
{ return n < 2 ? 1 : n * self(self, n - 1); });

assert( factorial(5) == 120 );
```

Did we succeed? Since the `fix_type<F>` object contains its own functor which it passes to it for each call, there is never a risk of a dangling reference. So our `factorial` object can truly be endless copied, moved from, in and out of functions without hassle.

Except... while the 'external' callers can readily make calls of the form `factorial(5)`, as it turns out inside our lambda expression the recursive call still looks like `self(self, /* actual interesting args */)`. We can improve on this by changing `fix_type` to not pass `functor` to itself, but by passing `*this` instead. That is, we pass in the `fix_type` object which is in charge of passing the correct 'implicit-as-explicit' argument in the first position: `return functor(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);`. Then the recursion becomes `n * self(n - 1)`, as it should be.

Finally, this is the generated code for a `main` that uses `return factorial(5);` instead of the assertion (for either flavour of `fix_type`):

```
00000000004005e0 <main>:
  4005e0:       b8 78 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x78
  4005e5:       c3                      ret    
  4005e6:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
```

The compiler was able to optimize everything away, as it would have done with a run-off-the-mill recursive function.

---

#### What are the costs?

The astute reader may have noticed one curious detail. In the move from a non-generic to a generic lambda, I added an explicit return type (i.e. `-> int`). How come?

This has to do with the fact that the return type to be deduced is the type of the conditional expression, which type depends on the call to `self`, which type is being deduced. A quick reading of [Return type deduction for normal functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html) would suggest that rewriting the lambda expression as follows should work:

```
[](auto&& self, int n)
{
    if(n < 2) return 1;               // return type is deduced here
    else return n * self(/* args */); // this has no impact
}
```

GCC will in fact accept this code with the first form of `fix_type` only (the one that passes `functor`). I'm not able to determine if it is right to complain about the other form (where `*this` is passed). I leave it to the reader to choose what trade-off to make: less type deduction, or less ugly recursive calls (it's also of course completely possible to have access to either flavour anyway).

---

#### GCC 4.9 examples

- [Complete code, first flavour](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/845e539a805f2658)
- [Complete code, second flavour](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/596268717ab16c94)
- [Complete code, first flavour, C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87812c680208564b)
- [An example of a variadic `fix` for a group of mutually recursive lambda expressions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dff32e33a322427f)

Comment: Not too hard to unroll... one member function `odd`, another `even`, then `operator()` that does the initial dispatch (I must admit I am just blindly guessing, I don't know what you refer to as *even/odd functions*)

Comment: While it explains why you can't easily create recursive lambdas _in general_, I fail to see why it's not allowed for simple captureless lambdas. After all, they can be thought as a simple function, just with local scope.

Answer (score 17):

It's not a lambda expression, but hardly more code, works with C++98, and *can* recurse:

```
struct {
    int operator()(int n) const {
        return n < 2 ? 1 : n * (*this)(n-1);
    }
} fact;
return fact(5);
```

According to `[class.local]/1`, it has access to all names that the enclosing function has access to, which is important for private names in a member function.

Of course, not being a lambda, you have to write a constructor if you want to capture state outside the function object.

Comment: Honestly, this is the most practical answer to recursive lambda functions. :)

Comment: best answer in the world