# C++1y return type inference

Tags: c++11, recursion, type-inference, c++14, return-type-deduction

Programming languages with some variant of Hindley-Milner type inference can easily infer the type of expressions such as

```
let rec fix f x = f (fix f) x
```

whereas the return type inference in C++1y fails for the following :

```
int main() {
  auto fix =
  [&](auto f) {
    return [&](auto x) {
      return f(fix(f))(x);
    };
  };
  return 0;
}
```

I tried this with clang 3.5 and the command

```
clang++ -std=c++1y fix.cc
```

and I get

```
fix.cc:7:18: error: variable 'fix' declared with 'auto' type cannot appear in its
own initializer
    return f(fix(f))(x);
```

What is lacking in C++'s return type inference that disallows using variable in it's own initializer when return type has to be inferred? What can I do to work around this problem, and better still, what can we do to fix this in the language?

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what this does (is intended to do): If you call `fix` supplying a function named `fun`, `fix(fun)` yields some `[&](auto x) { return fun(fix(fun)) (x); }`, where I can recursively replace `fix(fun)` with said expression. Even if `fun` had a fixed return type that didn't depend on the argument, I fail to see how this recursion ends.

Comment: Obviously, you can go to isocpp.org, find instruction on writing a proposal, write one that proposes new wording for the standard, explaining in details why this extension won't cause trouble, etc.

Comment: @dyp you don't recursively replace fix(fun). fix(fun) returns a function object g. g(x) call f(g) to get a function (object) h and then calls h(x).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Sorry but I don't understand it yet. Of course, `fix` is not *called* recursively (directly), but `f` may be overloaded or a template requiring the type of `fix(f)` (and its return type) for instantiation. The trivial example of the identity function therefore fails to compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74a447079f3a94bc

Comment: @dyp Didn't say it was going to work with any function. For f, instead of id, use a function that ignores its argument and returns an object of type id.

Comment: Some people like to call what languages like C++ perform ‘type deduction’ rather than ‘type inference’ (sometimes ‘*full* type inference’). The former doesn’t have the weight and formalization that the latter implies. That may just be my perception of things though.

Comment: I have [a demonstration of a fix-like construct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085331/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c1y) for C++1y lambdas. It’s quite interesting to try and omit as many explicit return types to see how the compiler can deal with it. In any case, I cannot tell when and why any would be needed with certainty.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here isn't a problem with type inference. The immediate issue is simply that no syntax exists for a lambda to refer to itself even though doing so is perfectly reasonable and implementable. Function objects can easily be defined that refer to themselves.

Your particular lambda has a problem in that you are capturing a local object by reference and then allowing that reference to escape the scope where it's valid, but if we change it to:

```
int main() {
  auto fix =
  [](auto &f) {
    return [&](auto x) {
      return f(fix(f))(x);
    };
  };
  return 0;
}
```

Then we can write and use equivalent function objects:

```
#include <iostream>

struct lambda1 {
    template<typename F>
    auto operator() (F &f) const;
};

template<typename F>
struct lambda2 {
    lambda1 const &l1;
    F &f;
    lambda2(lambda1 const &l1, F &f) : l1(l1), f(f) {}

    template<typename X>
    auto operator() (X x) const { return f( l1(f))(x); }
}; 

template<typename F>
auto lambda1::operator() (F &f) const {
    return lambda2<F>(*this, f);
}   //                  ^
    //                  |
    //                  --- there's no syntax to do this inside a lambda.

int main() {
  lambda1 fix;
  auto f = [](auto&&){ return [](int x) {return x;}; };
  std::cout << fix(f)(5) << '\n';
}
```

If some kind of syntax were added to allow a lambda to refer to itself then this would be fine.

Comment: [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dc2b78be8c0137b) with a (useless) invocation.  The above has the problem that the `operator()` body is not compiled unless and until it is called.

Comment: @Yakk in my program that template operator() isn't instantiated, but it can be and it does work correctly without any modification: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34c77cf8cdd4b492

Comment: *nod* -- you'll notice (other than some perfect forwarding) my code is identical to yours.  I was just noting the missing bit of the above code I felt I had to check to ensure it actually works.  :)

Comment: @Yakk Ah, okay. I've modified my answer to actually instantiate and run the code.