# Recursion with generic lambda functions in C++14

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, c++14, auto

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18085331/7893951) question, where the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18085333/7893951) describes nice detail about how can the generic lambda functions be used to replace the [`std::function` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067988/7893951) and how to rewire the stop condition to enable the return type deduction.

Based on the above I created the following working example:

```
#include <cstdio>

void printSeq(unsigned start) {
    auto recursion = [](auto&& self, const char* format, unsigned current) {
        printf(format, current);
        if(!current)
            return static_cast<void>(printf("\n"));
        else
            self(self, ", %u", current - 1);
    };

    recursion(recursion, "%u", start);
}

int main() {
    return (printSeq(15), 0);
}
```

My question is that what's the advantage using `auto&&` over the `auto&` in this case? Should I use the `std::move` here?

Comment: One thing to note is that since `recursion` doesn't capture anything, it's just a trivial object, so there will be no benefit from using `std::move`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto&` is lvalue only.

This matters little until you refactor and replace the lvalue recursive object with a temporary proxy memoizer, for example.

`auto&&` is harmless, and means "I do not mind if this is a temprary or whatever, just don't make a copy", which expresses meaning well here.  `auto&` states "No temporaries allowed!"  Sometimes you want to exclude temporaries when making a reference, but it is rare.

`auto const&`, `auto` and `auto&&`  should be your bread and butter.

Only use `auto&` if your operation is explicitly about writing *and* you are ok with excluding proxy references.