# Discrepancy with lambda conversion constructor in GCC/MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, c++11

Which one, if not both, is breaking spec? Tried with MSVC on both MSVC 2013 and MSVC Nov 2013 CTP, GCC was MinGW x64 4.9.1 with -std=c++11.

```
template<typename ret_type>
class memoizer
{
    using func_type = ret_type(*)(const int);
    const func_type func;

    std::map<int, ret_type> cache;

public:
    memoizer(func_type func) : func(func)
    {
    }

    ret_type operator [](const int n)
    {
        const auto it = cache.find(n);
        if(it != cache.end())
            return it->second;

        return cache[n] = func(n);
    }
};

//works in GCC but not MSVC
//error C2065: 'fib' : undeclared identifier
memoizer<int64_t> fib([](const int n)
{
    return n < 2 ? n : fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2];
});

//works in MSVC but not GCC
//error: conversion from '<lambda(int)>' to non-scalar type 'memoizer<long long int>' requested
memoizer<int64_t> fib = [](const int n)
{
    return n < 2 ? n : fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2];
};
```

This seems to stem from the way they're handling lambda types differently, and when they consider a variable to be defined.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c0x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC is right.

For your first form:

A variable is considered declared at the end of its declarator, which is before its initialiser. This is why the this form is valid. The famous example is `int i = i;`, which is syntactically valid and initialises `i` with its own (indeterminate) value.

For your second form:

Your initialisation with `=` fails because you have two user-defined conversions. (The lambda type's conversion operator is considered user-defined.) It is analogous to

```
struct A { };
struct B { B(A) { } };
struct C { C(B) { } };
A a;
C c1(a); // okay
C c2 = a; // error
```

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour It just follows from how the standard describes the conversion (5.1.2p6), if I understand your question correctly: it is defined as a conversion function that gets defined on the lambda type, instead of being a special rule in the language defining an additional standard conversion.

Comment: I was looking for the quote, I see it, makes sense.