# Lambda function - capturing by value

Tags: c++, lambda

Why does this result in a segmentation fault?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main() {

     function<int(int,int)> hcf = [=](int m, int n)mutable->int{
    // cout << "m: " << m << " n: " << n << endl;
    if(m<n) return hcf(n,m);
    int remainder(m%n);
    if(0 == remainder) return n;
    return hcf(n,remainder);
};

    cout << hcf(10,15) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have added the `mutable` keyword. Shouldn't pass-by-value work? Why does this require pass-by-reference? Is it because I am calling `hcf` recursively?

Comment: capturing by value `hcf` at the point it's not initialized doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: You don't supply the error message. Funnily enough it works for me without error. Although I am wondering how it captures `cout` by copy - shouldn't that be deleted?

Comment: this question should not be downvoted, it can become a common problem soon

Comment: @Galik: `std::cout` is a global instance, does not need to be captured. and it compiles, but it should throw exception `std::bad_function_call`

Comment: I meant it results in a segmentation fault. I was running this on an online compiler and it just said runtime error.

Comment: @Galik I have updated the code. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I think I get it now. That it uses `cout` without capturing it is a big clue as to why it works as a global `lambda` but not as a local `lambda`. When it is global it can call itself without having to capture itself. When its local it needs to capture itself to call itself and so capture by copy is problematic!

Comment: Could someone give me a link to the specs for this? I couldn't find documentation for this behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive lambda functions in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closure object is initialized before `hcf` as it is `hcf`'s initializer. Even if your code wouldn't invoke UB you would still copy `hcf`s still empty state into the member variable of the closure object. Subsequently calling it would then result in calling an empty `function`.

When you capture by reference this isn't a problem anymore as with the references first use (that is, the first call to the closure object), `hcf` has already been properly initialized.