# Is there this in lambda body?

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda

Is there a way to refer to the closure object from inside its `operator()`?
Simplified version of what I'd like to do with `Boost.Asio`:

```
tcp::acceptor acceptor;

auto handler = [&acceptor]( )
{
    // ...
    acceptor.async_accept( *this );
};

acceptor.async_accept( handler );
```

But there is no separate `this` for lambdas.
And I cannot capture reference to handler, because its type isn't yet known.
The only workaround I see now is to write separate functor class, simply because there is a `this`-pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you cannot write recursive lambdas in C++11, 14 and 17, nor collections of mutually recursive lambdas.

Several future extensions have been suggested that would enable this, but nothing is decided as of yet. Current workarounds consist of creating a type-erasing `std::function` wrapper, or indeed as you point out, to just write your own functor classes.

(The latter is generally always an option when you have a question of the sort "can lambdas do X" -- lambdas are just syntactic sugar around existing language features, and those features will always be there when you need them.)

Comment: Well, the better work-around is [using a Y-combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40873657/3204551). After defining it once, one can always reuse it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Thanks for the link. That's certainly a nice piece of code, though I'd put that in the "custom class" kind of solution. You could perhaps also make a case about that solution requiring templates (even for one specific instance of recursion), when a case-specific custom class might be able to do the same job but be simpler. But it looks like a nice tool for sure.

Comment: ha! never tried or even got interest in std::function, but it turned out super easy and almost as concise as lambda itself! to fix my original code, what is only needed is replace auto with std::function< void () > and then it is possible to capture it. thanks! :)

Comment: @VasylDemianov: Yes, but beware that this comes at significant runtime cost, since `std::function` type-erases the callable, and so there's a dynamic dispatch involved at every call.

Comment: @KerrekSB, why significant? It's only virtual method call, basically one additional dereference, no?
I have an idea how it works, I implemented shared pointer and its shared state object as an excercise, pretty neat. :)

Comment: @VasylDemianov: Well, it's significant in general, since the cost *may* be high compared to the cost of the lambda body itself. It is of course possible to have a situation where the cost is insignificant. But for a general-purpose answer the cost should be pointed out, and it's up to you whether you can tolerate it.