# How is it possible to write f( *this, std::forward<Args>(args)... ) whereas f is only declared with F f;

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

In this reply
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58737595
please, can you explan how it is possible to write :

```
return f( f, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
```

whereas f is only declared as : 
    `F f;`
and we don't know that f is a function accepting 2 parameters a priori.
Thank you for your explanation.

I would be grateful for the deep explanations

Comment: Well this only compiles if F is a type that has a `operator()` with the given parameter types. This is checked by the compiler once the template is instantiated and if F does not fit the requirements, the compiler will exit with an error.

Comment: If it walks like a duck...

Comment: @eike or F is a function (pointer) type

Comment: I have updated my first message and the line of code to make my question more clear

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need some good C++ tutorial/book, specifically about templates.

The piece of code you're referring to is a templated `struct`.

```cpp
template<class F>
struct y_combinator {
  F f;
 /* more code */
}
```

It means that whenever we want to use it we have to specify the template parameter.

```cpp
y_combinator<int> y_int;
```

When we use our templated `struct` like that, the compiler will generate a new `struct`, let's call it y_combinator_int, and replace all occurences of `F` with `int`.

The important thing is that templates use duck typing, if you do something that's illegal/makes no sense, you will get a compile time error (currently such errors are really hard to read, but with C++20 we will probably get more human readable errors).

Overall templates are a very complicated subject, if you want to learn them you need to find a good tutorial/book.

Comment: I have updated the line of code of my first message

Comment: The anserw remains the same, templates use duck typing. We don't know if F has such operator, but when we specify the type of F, like in my code example, the compiler will generate needed code and functions, which can result in a compilation error

Comment: [This error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbecc120ce01e971) isn't that cryptic: