# constexpr recursive function defined via lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

Is there a convenient way to define a recursive constexpr function by using the lambda syntax? I found an *inconvenient* way to do it by assigning to a `constexpr` function pointer, but I'd like a way to do this with less typing and without changing the type of the lambda.

Making a recursive constexpr function in the ordinary way is pretty straightforward.
In particular, using a single expression, possibly containing ternary operators has been supported since C++11.

```
constexpr double factorial2(double x) {
    return (x < 0) ? 0 : \
           (x == 0) ? 1 : \
           /*otherwise*/ (x * factorial2(-1 + x));
}
```

It is less clear how to do this using the lambda syntax. I'll include my various failed attempts below, but I found a way to make a constexpr function by using a `constexpr` function pointer instead of `auto` as the type annotation for the variable I'm intializing with my lambda.

```
typedef double (* factorial_t)(double);

constexpr factorial_t factorial = [](double x) constexpr noexcept -> double {
    return (x < 0) ? 0 : \
           (x == 0) ? 1 : \
           /*otherwise*/ (x * factorial(-1 + x));
};
```

Clang will accept this, and so will GCC 9.2 on godbolt.

```
// foo.cpp
#include <cstdio>

typedef double (* factorial_t)(double);

constexpr factorial_t factorial = [](double x) constexpr noexcept -> double {
    return (x < 0) ? 0 : \
           (x == 0) ? 1 : \
           /*otherwise*/ (x * factorial(-1 + x));
};


int main() {
    constexpr auto x{factorial(27)};
    printf("%f\n", x);
}
```

And running it:

```
$ rm -f ./a.out && clang++-7 -std=c++17 foo.cpp && ./a.out
10888869450418351940239884288.000000
```

---

This section is just an appendix explaining why I decided to use a function pointer rather than something else.

Failed attempts to produce a recursive constexpr function via lambda.

1) using `auto`

As explained [in this somewhat old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c11), using the name of the thing you're defining inside the lambda is allowed, but doesn't interact well with type inference. The answers suggested using `std::function`

```
auto factorial = [](double x) constexpr noexcept -> double {
    return (x < 0) ? 0 : \
           (x == 0) ? 1 : \
           /*otherwise*/ (x * factorial(-1 + x));
};
```

error:

```
bar.cpp:7:31: error: variable 'factorial' declared with deduced type 'auto' cannot appear in its own initializer
           /*otherwise*/ (x * factorial(-1 + x));
```

2) using `std::function`.

This doesn't work because a `std::function` is a non-literal type. Apparently.

```
// bar.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

constexpr std::function<double(double)> factorial = [](double x) constexpr noexcept -> double {
    return (x < 0) ? 0 : \
           (x == 0) ? 1 : \
           /*otherwise*/ (x * factorial(-1 + x));
};


int main() {
    constexpr auto x{factorial(27)};
    printf("%f\n", x);
}
```

Fails with the error message:

```
bar.cpp:5:41: error: constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const std::function<double (double)>'
constexpr std::function<double(double)> factorial = [](double x) constexpr noexcept -> double {
                                        ^
    /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1834:11: note: 'function<double (double)>' is
          not literal because it is not an aggregate and has no constexpr constructors other than copy or move constructors
        class function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
```

Comment: This looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40873505/2752075

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Dirty trick... will it work in a constexpr context?

Comment: @einpoklum I don't see why it wouldn't but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a trick due to a [blog post by Pedro Melendez](http://pedromelendez.com/blog/2015/07/16/recursive-lambdas-in-c14/), which circumvents direct recursion, and can be used in a constexpr context. Thanks @HolbyBlackCat for the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40873505/2752075) and the idea.

```
constexpr auto factorial = [](int n) {
    auto factorial_impl = [](int n, auto& factorial_ref) {
        if(n <= 1) { return 1; }
        return n * factorial_ref(n-1, factorial_ref);
    };
    return factorial_impl(n,factorial_impl);
};
```

[See it on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/2zL36e).

The (external) lambda is a "closure type", which became "literal" and usable with `constexpr` only in C++17 (so this won't work with C++14).

PS - I simplified your factorial function a bit and am using integers because IMHO the use of doubles just distracts from what the question is about.