# return type deduction of recursive function

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction, generic-lambda

Recently, I read [Barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40873657/6793559) to this question [Recursive lambda functions in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067988/6793559):

```cpp
template <class F>
struct y_combinator {
    F f; // the lambda will be stored here

    // a forwarding operator():
    template <class... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        // we pass ourselves to f, then the arguments.
        // [edit: Barry] pass in std::ref(*this) instead of *this
        return f(std::ref(*this), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
// deduction guide
template <class F> y_combinator(F) -> y_combinator<F>;
```

Basically, `y_combinator` allows one to write a recursive lambda expression more easily (e.g. without having to delcare a `std::function`). When I played with `y_combinator`, I found something strange:

```cpp
int main() {
   // Case #1 compiles fine
   y_combinator{[](auto g, int a, int b) {
      if (a >= b) return 0;
      return 1 + g(a + 1, b);
    }}(1, 2);

    // Case #2 deos not compile
    y_combinator{[](auto g, int a) {
      if (a >= 0) return 0;
      return 1 + g(a + 1);
    }}(1);

    // Case #3 compiles just fine
    y_combinator{[](auto g, int a)->int {
      if (a >= 0) return 0;
      return 1 + g(a + 1);
    }}(1);
}
```

Case #1 and Case #3 compile fine while Case #2 does not compile. I got the same result with Clang 10.0 and GCC 9.3. 
For Case #2, Clang says

```
prog.cc:25:18: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::__1::reference_wrapper<const y_combinator<(lambda at prog.cc:23:18)> >'
      return 1 + g(a + 1);
                 ^
```

1. How is the different results between Case #1 and Case #2?
2. Why does the trailing return type make a difference between Case #2 and Case #3?

You can check it on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/niKIzjYWatSCAB2R).

Comment: maybe because it can't deduce the return type?...

Comment: @Berto99 then how it can deduce the return type in Case #1?

Comment: As far as I can see, [\[dcl.spec.auto\]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#10) should allow both to deduce a return type.

Comment: @aschepler - in the example you cite (if I understand correctly what you mean) the return type of `sum()` is deduced because `sum()` call itself; in this case the lambda call `g()` that call lambda... I'm not sure is the same thing from the return-type-deduction point of view.

Comment: @max66 Yes, that could complicate things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in #1 the initial and recursive calls to `y_combinator` have different argument types, whereas in #2 they have the same argument types (including value category).

In #1, the initial arguments `(1, 2)` are both int prvalue, whereas the recursive arguments `g(a + 1, b)` are respectively int prvalue and int lvalue. Meanwhile in #2 the initial argument `(1)` and recursive argument `g(a + 1)` are both int prvalue. You can check that making a change to #1 such that both recursive arguments are int prvalue (e.g. calling `g(a + 1, b + 0)`) will [break](https://godbolt.org/z/4pjVq9) it, while changing #2 to pass int lvalue as the recursive argument (e.g. `g(++a)`) will [fix](https://godbolt.org/z/NkJynu) it.

This means that the return type deduction *for the initial call* is self-referential, in that it depends on the type of *precisely* the same call to `y_combinator<lambda #2>::operator()<int>(int&&)` (whereas in #1 the initial call to `y_combinator<lambda #1>::operator()<int, int>(int&&, int&&)` depends on `y_combinator<lambda #1>::operator()<int, int&>(int&&, int&)`).

Supplying the return type explicitly as in #3 means there is no self-referential type deduction, and everything is fine.

You might ask, why is #1 OK given that the *recursive* case is still self-referential (noting that all 3 compilers agree). This is because once we can get into the lambda's own type deduction, [[dcl.spec.auto]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#10) kicks in and the first `return` statement gives a return type to the lambda, so when it recursively calls `g`, that type deduction has already succeeded.

A diagram usually helps:

```
y_combinator<lambda #1>::operator()<int, int>
 -> forwards to [lambda #1]::operator()<y_combinator<lambda #1>> {
     has return type int by [dcl.spec.auto]/10
     calls y_combinator<lambda #1>::operator()<int, int&> (not previously seen)
      -> forwards to [lambda #1]::operator()<y_combinator<lambda #1>>
      -> already deduced to return int
      -> this is OK
 }

y_combinator<lambda #2>::operator()<int>
  -> forwards to [lambda #2]::operator()<y_combinator<lambda #2>> {
     has return type int by [dcl.spec.auto]/10
     calls y_combinator<lambda #2>::operator()<int>
     but y_combinator<lambda #2>::operator()<int> has incomplete return type at this point
      -> error
  }
```

A [fix](https://godbolt.org/z/etZb5T) (thanks to @aschepler) is to remember the argument lists that the lambda has been called with already, and provide a "clean" wrapper whose functional call operator(s) are not yet undergoing return type deduction for each new set of argument types:

```
template<class...> struct typelist {};

template<class T, class... Ts>
constexpr bool any_same = (std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...);

template <class F>
struct y_combinator {
    template <class... TLs>
    struct ref {
        y_combinator& self;
        template <class... Args>
        decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const {
            using G = std::conditional_t<
                any_same<typelist<Args...>, TLs...>,
                ref<TLs...>,
                ref<TLs..., typelist<Args...>>>;
            return self.f(G{self}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
    F f;
    template <class... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
        return ref<>{*this}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
template <class F> y_combinator(F) -> y_combinator<F>;
```

Comment: Bingo! The diagrams are missing the involvement of `std::reference_wrapper`, and each `[lambda #N]::operator()` only has one template argument, which is always a `std::reference_wrapper<const y_combinator<lambda #N>>`.

Comment: @aschepler as far as I can tell `reference_wrapper` [doesn't make a difference](https://godbolt.org/z/_Yip9Z) either way (with trunk compilers in C++20 mode, anyway), so I left it out of the diagrams for conciseness. I see what you mean about only having 1 template argument, though - fixed.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair.

Comment: We could probably workaround fancier by returning wrapper types that track a sequence of tuples of template argument types already "seen". If really necessary.

Comment: @aschepler I think we only need to remember the current arguments, so [this](https://godbolt.org/z/XZeWk2) should work - let me know if you can break it.

Comment: Can break if not every functor call satisfies [dcl.spec.auto]/10: https://godbolt.org/z/XV7BgY Done here using multiple `operator()`, but presumably an `if constexpr` on a `return` before the recursive call could do the same thing.

Comment: It does work if "remembering" all past argument tuples: https://godbolt.org/z/KqToej I tried various things to get around MSVC's confusion, but haven't solved that part yet.

Comment: Wow. I figured this was just a bug or something :-)

Comment: @aschepler Oh, that's evil (the multiple operator()) :). Getting MSVC to cooperate isn't too hard, I just moved the comparison out into an `any_same` metafunction so it isn't trying to expand too many packs at the same time. Also replaced the enable_if with a conditional_t and tuple with a lightweight typelist: https://godbolt.org/z/kRqury

Comment: @ecatmur Thanks for your detailed answer. The diagrams really help! There is a typo in the first sentence of the 3rd paragraph, should be "This means that (in #2) the return type deduction for the initial **call** is self-referential", correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @aschepler unfortunately your solution fails for passing `3` instead of `3u` as the initial argument: https://godbolt.org/z/qe9zx5 I'm not sure there is a general solution that can handle `overload`, and modern code should probably be using `if constexpr` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code:

```
template <class F>
struct y_combinator {
    F f; // the lambda will be stored here

    // a forwarding operator():
    template <class... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        // we pass ourselves to f, then the arguments.
        // [edit: Barry] pass in std::ref(*this) instead of *this
        return f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

without the `std::ref` (which is used for efficiency i believe, because you don't copy the object over and over) errors changes to

```
prog.cc:23:18: error: function 'operator()<int>' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
```

So probably the compiler can't figure out the return type, but i can't tell you how in the first case it can deduce it