# deduce return type of function template before instantiation

Tags: c++

This is a follow up question for [return type deduction of recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62161963/6793559).

```cpp
template <class F>
struct y_combinator {
    F f; // the lambda will be stored here

    // a forwarding operator():
    template <class... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        // we pass ourselves to f, then the arguments.
        // [edit: Barry] pass in std::ref(*this) instead of *this
        return f(std::ref(*this), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
// deduction guide
template <class F> y_combinator(F) -> y_combinator<F>;
```

Basically, `y_combinator` allows one to write a recursive lambda expression more easily (e.g. without having to delcare a `std::function`).

In this question, consider the case where [[dcl.spec.auto]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#10) does not apply (i.e. no return statement before recursive call).

```cpp
// this does not compile
y_combinator{
// lets call the lambda expression #1
[](auto g, int i) {
  for (int j = i; j < 10; ++j) {
    g(j + 1);
  }
}}(1);
```

[live example](https://godbolt.org/z/jqa_JL)

According to [ecatmur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162388/6793559) to the original question, the above code fails becuase

```
y_combinator<lambda #1>::operator()<int> instantiates
  -> [lambda #1]::operator()<y_combinator<lambda #1>> instantiates
       -> need to know return type of y_combinator<lambda #1>::operator()<int> at the point of g(j+1);
       -> fail!
```

However, the compiler may well know that the return type of `F::operator()` is `void` before the first instantiation `y_combinator<lambda #1>::operator()<int>`.

1. Why the return type of lambda #1 (and thus the return type of `F::operator()`) is not deduced when the temporary `y_combinator` object is constructed?
2. Is it possible to make the code compile without adding trailing return type `-> void` to lambda #1?

Answer (score 0):

To deduce the return type, the compiler must instantiate the generic lambda. It does it, the code is ill formed because he cannot deduce the type of `g(j+1)`.

To be able to compile this code the compiler should make an induction:

1. Let's suppose that the return value of `g(j+1)` is such that the generic lambda call operator instantiation is well formed.
2. So the generic lambda instantiation succeed and its return type is void
3. so the y_combinator call operator return type is void
4. so indeed the first hypothesys is correct!

Maybe that when compiler will be able to do that, computer will code themselves!

So no it is not possible not to use the trailing return type. Or do better, just use a function. Lambda are devils that cause template instantiation explosion.