# How do I manage declarations that require template parameters derived from recursive functors/lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, y-combinator

I am attempting to build a clean and neat implementation of recursive-capable lambda self-scoping (which is basically a Y-combinator although I think technically not quite). It's a journey that's taken me to, among many others, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40873657/7957776) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66014453/7957776) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497003).

I've boiled down one of my issues as cleanly as I can: how do I pass around templated functors which take lambdas as their template parameters?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#define uint unsigned int

template <class F>
class Functor {
public:
    F m_f;

    template <class... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
        return m_f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
template <class F> Functor(F)->Functor<F>;

class B {
private:
    uint m_val;
public:
    B(uint val) : m_val(val) {}
    uint evaluate(Functor<decltype([](auto & self, uint val)->uint {})> func) const {
        return func(m_val);
    }
};

int main() {
    B b = B(5u);
    Functor f = Functor{[](auto& self, uint val) -> uint {
        return ((2u * val) + 1u);
    }};

    std::cout << "f applied to b is " << b.evaluate(f) << "." << std::endl;
}
```

The code above does not work, with Visual Studio claiming that `f` (in the `b.evaluate(f)` call) does not match the parameter type.

My assumption is that `auto & self` is not clever enough to make this work. How do I get around this? How do I store and pass these things around when they are essentially undefinable? Is this why many of the Y-combinator implementations I've seen have the strange double-wrapped thing?

Any help or explanation would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: The body of a lambda is basically a part of its type; different lambdas are different types. Of course your code doesn't work, because the only kind of `func` it will take is the one you've written right there in the signature, which does nothing. It's not `auto&`'s place or ability to change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The easiest solution is:

```
uint evaluate(std::function<uint(uint)> func) const {
    return func(m_val);
}
```

a step up would be to write a `function_view`.

```
uint evaluate(function_view<uint(uint)> func) const {
    return func(m_val);
}
```

(there are dozens of implementations on the net, should be easy to find).

## The easiest and most runtime efficient is:

```
template<class F>
uint evaluate(F&& func) const {
    return func(m_val);
}
```

because *we don't care* what `func` is, we just want it to quack like a duck.  If you want to check it early...

```
template<class F> requires (std::is_convertible_v< std::invoke_result_t< F&, uint >, uint >)
uint evaluate(F&& func) const {
    return func(m_val);
}
```

using [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), or using [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)

```
template<class F,
  std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v< std::invoke_result_t< F&, uint >, uint >), bool> = true
>
uint evaluate(F&& func) const {
    return func(m_val);
}
```

which is similar just more obscure.

You can write a fixes-signature type-erased `Functor`, but I think it is a bad idea.  It looks like:

```
template<class R, class...Args>
using FixedSignatureFunctor = Functor< std::function<R( std::function<R(Args...)>, Args...) > >;
```

or slightly more efficient

```
template<class R, class...Args>
using FixedSignatureFunctor = Functor< function_view<R( std::function<R(Args...)>, Args...) > >;
```

but this is pretty insane; you'd want to forget what the `F` is, but not that you can replace the `F`!

To make this fully "useful", you'd have to add smart copy/move/assign operations to `Functor`, where it can be copied if the `F`s inside each of them can be copied.

```
template <class F>
class Functor {
public:
  // ...
  Functor(Functor&&)=default;
  Functor& operator=(Functor&&)=default;
  Functor(Functor const&)=default;
  Functor& operator=(Functor const&)=default;

  template<class O> requires (std::is_constructible_v<F, O&&>)
  Functor(Functor<O>&& o):m_f(std::move(o.m_f)){}
  template<class O> requires (std::is_constructible_v<F, O const&>)
  Functor(Functor<O> const& o):m_f(o.m_f){}
  template<class O> requires (std::is_assignable_v<F, O&&>)
  Functor& operator=(Functor<O>&& o){
    m_f = std::move(o.mf);
    return *this;
  }
  template<class O> requires (std::is_assignable_v<F, O const&>)
  Functor& operator=(Functor<O> const& o){
    m_f = o.mf;
    return *this;
  }
  // ...
};
```

([c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) version, replace requires clauses with `std::enable_if_t` SFINAE hack in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and before).

## How to decide

The core thing to remember here is that C++ has more than one kind of polymorphism, and using the wrong kind will make you waste a lot of time.

There is both compile time polymorphism and runtime polymorphism.  Using runtime polymorphism when you only need compile time polymorphism is a waste.

Then in each category, there are even more subtypes.

`std::function` is a runtime polymorphic type erasure regular object.  Inheritance based virtual functions is another runtime polymorphic technique.

Your Y-combinator is doing compile time polymorphism.  It changes what it stores and exposed a more uniform interface.

Things talking to that interface **don't care** about the internal implementation details of your Y-combinator, and including them in their implementation is an abstraction failure.

`evaluate` takes a callable thing and pass it in `uint` and expects a `uint` in return.  That is what it care about.  It doesn't **care** if it is passed a `Functor<Chicken>` or a function pointer.

Making it care about it is a mistake.

If it takes a `std::function`, it does runtime polymorphism; if it takes a `template<class F>` with an argument of type `F&&`, it is compile time polymorphic.  This is a choice, and they are different.

Taking a `Functor<F>` of any kind is putting contract requirements in its API it fundamentally shouldn't care about.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I see is make `evaluate()` a template method; if you want to be sure to receive a `Functor` (but you can simply accept a callable: see [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66068416/6022656)):

```
template <typename F>
uint evaluate(Functor<F> func) const {
    return func(m_val);
}
```

Take in count that every lambda is a different type, as you can verify with the following trivial code

```
auto l1 = []{};
auto l2 = []{};

static_assert( not std::is_same_v<decltype(l1), decltype(l2)> );
```

so impose a particular lambda type to `evaluate()` can't work because if you call the method with (apparently) the same lambda function, the call doesn't match, as you can see in the following example

```
auto l1 = []{};
auto l2 = []{};

void foo (decltype(l1))
 { }

int main ()
 {
   foo(l2); // compilation error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
 }
```

Comment: I see. I hadn't grasped that last point about lambdas being different types; I assumed they would work more like std::function, where functions with the same input and output types are of the same type.

Comment: `Function<std::function<R(Args...)>` also works.  But no, @StefanBauer, lamdas do not have a common type. That would add runtime overhead, and they are intended to give you hand-crafted inlined code speed.  `std::function` can give them a common binary interface, but that is optional.

Comment: @StefanBauer - Unfortunately not: lambda are syntactic sugar for unnamed structs with `operator()`, so the first `[]{}` is almost `struct unnamed_1 { void operator() () {} };` and the second one is `struct unnamed_2 { void operator() () {} };`. `unnamed_1` and  `unnamed_2` are substantially identically but formally different types.

Comment: @max66 Using LSP, what does two lambdas with the same signature but a template `operator()` have in common?  (it really isn't much; in a very fundamental way, a lambda's type is dependent on its entire body, which makes a common base class crazy; either that type has to be determined by the lambda function's body, or it doesn't help much)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - About the `std::function` hypothesis... in this case we have a generic lambda... which `std::function` can accept it?

Comment: @max66 `std::function< R(std::function<R(Args...)>, Args...)>` to be more exact.  The overhead is horrible (all calls copy the lambda and wrapper!).  A `std::function< R( function_view<R(Args...)>, Args..). >` would be better, but `std` doesn't have a `function_view`.  You do need to know what the arguments you are passing to the "lambda" are for this to work.

Comment: @max66 I added more details in my answer below.  Enjoy!

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - I just missed `FixedSignatureFunctor` :-)