# A Problem with Recursive Void Lambda Expressions in C++

Tags: c++, g++

I would like to implement *recursive void lambda expressions* inside a function. I have created the C++ snippet below to illustrate my problem. `Lambda` is the recursive void lambda expression I would like to build inside `Func1`. However, when I compile with `g++`, I run into the following compiler errors:

```
Lambda_void.cpp: In function ‘void Func1(std::vector<int>&)’:
Lambda_void.cpp:6:10: error: variable or field ‘Lambda’ declared void
     void Lambda = [](std::vector<int> &A)
          ^~~~~~
Lambda_void.cpp: In lambda function:
Lambda_void.cpp:11:13: error: ‘Lambda’ was not declared in this scope
             Lambda(A);
             ^~~~~~
Lambda_void.cpp:11:13: note: suggested alternative: ‘__lambda0’
             Lambda(A);
             ^~~~~~
             __lambda0
Lambda_void.cpp: In function ‘void Func1(std::vector<int>&)’:
Lambda_void.cpp:14:5: error: ‘Lambda’ was not declared in this scope
     Lambda(A);
     ^~~~~~
```

Changing to the lambda variable declaration from `void` to `auto` does not solve anything as the compiler has not identified the variable type before the first recursion. Are there any possible workarounds here? And why doesn't `g++` allow to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void Func1(std::vector<int> &A)
{
    void Lambda = [](std::vector<int> &A)
    {
        while (A.size() < 5)
        {
            A.push_back(1);
            Lambda(A);
        }
    };
    Lambda(A);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> C;
    Func1(C);
    for (auto& i : C) {std::cout << i << " ";}
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c11) question for recursive lamda-functions explanation. You can declare your Lambda as `std::function<void(std::vector<int>&)>` and capture it inside lambda:

```cpp
std::function<void(std::vector<int>&)> Lambda;
Lambda = [&Lambda](std::vector<int>& A) {
    while (A.size() < 5) {
        A.push_back(1);
        Lambda(A);
    }
};
Lambda(A);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the internal lambda has not yet been instantiated, you cannot deduce its return type.
One of the workarounds is to pass the lambda itself as a parameter ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9T1haPfd4)):

```
auto Lambda = [](std::vector<int> &A, auto self) -> void
{
    while (A.size() < 5)
    {
        A.push_back(1);
        self(A, self);
    }
};
Lambda(A, Lambda);
```

But this is obviously very redundant, so the better way is to just use the free function for the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

`void` doesn't work as the type of a lambda isn't `void`.

Convert the lambda to a std::function and capture a reference to that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

void Func1(std::vector<int> &A)
{
    std::function<void(std::vector<int>&)> Lambda = [&](std::vector<int> &A)
    {
        while (A.size() < 5)
        {
            A.push_back(1);
            Lambda(A);
        }
    };
    Lambda(A);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> C;
    Func1(C);
    for (auto& i : C) {std::cout << i << " ";}
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```