# Recursive function and variable storage

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I am a C++ beginner and I have a question

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
void f (int);
int main ()
{
  f (2);
  return 0;
}

 void
f (int x)
{
   int a = 1;
   int b = 2;
   int i;
   if (x == 1)
     cout << a << b;
   if (x > 1)
    {
      a=2;
      b=1;
      f (x-1);
    }
}
```

The outcome would be 12, which means that variable a=1 and b=2

What I am thinking about is that is there any way I can use a new set of variables in each recursion?(that is, when I call f(2),I can let a be 2 and b be 1.)

I thought of static variable and reference, but I still can't figure out a resolution.

P.s. It was when I was writing the code of hanoi tower that I came up with this question. If this problem is solved, maybe I don't need to use 4-variable function but 1 instead.

I want some new ideas.

Comment: Convert your function into a function object that has a state `(a, b)`.

Comment: Please give a proper example for what you want.

Comment: Please provide other examples where you don't pass 2 as argument, but maybe 5 or 9, ... so we can see what you expect to happen then.

Comment: Why do you want to jump through hoops just to avoid passing arguments to a function? `f(x, a, b)` calls `f(x-1, b, a)` is the normal way of doing it.

Comment: I can't givve a proper example because l'm not quite sure how to write the hanai tower question if the problem is fixed lol(l just have a vague ideal). I think maybe setting a and b as the variables is really the only way. Thank you guys and sorry for causing any confusion.

Comment: While you could store these values somewhere else as a mutable state, juggling them around before recursing and restoring the state correctly after returning quickly becomes messy and very easy to get wrong (in particular when you get more of them and the values aren't hardcoded, as in the Towers of Hanoi). It is much easier to let the machine handle it for you and not worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, as soon as the execution passes a curly brace, every single variable defined in that set of curly braces is *gone*. This is called [scope](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-local-scope/).

Even a nested function cannot access any variables from the outer function. In your case, the function defines a and b as 1 and 2 before executing the case when a is 1.

In competitive programming, this is usually resolved with global variables which other programming people might think of as bad code style.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
void f (int);
int main ()
{
  f (2);
  return 0;
}
int a = 1, b = 2; // Global variables!
 void
f (int x)
{
   if (x == 1)
     cout << a << b;
   if (x == 2)
    {
      a = 2;
      b = 1;
      f (1);
    }
}
```

This code should print 21 as you want. In modern C++, one might nest the function inside the main function as a lambda function and make the variables persist with [lambda captures](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/lambda-captures/). However, [recursive functions require some work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c11). In C++23, you can use `this`, which is currently unfortunately only supported in the latest versions of MSVC and EDG eccp.

```cpp
int a = 1, b = 2; // Local variables
auto f = [&a, &b] /* ← Lambda captures! */ (this auto const &f, int x) {
    if (x == 1) cout << a << b;
    if (x == 2) {
        a = 2;
        b = 1;
        f(1);
    }
};
```

Comment: But using global would only be useful when l call f(2).l will edit my question to make it easier to understand my thought.

Comment: Yes, it would only be useful when you call f(2). There's no problem with that. If you don't somehow make the function access some persisting variables, this doesn't work. You can also make the function also have the parameters `const &a, const&b` ([passing by reference](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/pass-by-const-lvalue-reference/)) but I think that's a bit unwieldy as you'll have to put these vars in every time.

Comment: I wrote it without confirming anything. I've fixed some errors but there's still one remaining. I'll check it out...

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite understand lambda but l will try to fix it out 

Answer (score 1):

To output "21" you would need the variables `a` and `b` to be `static`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void f(int);

int main() {
    f(2);
    return 0;
}

void f(const int x) {
    static int a = 1;
    static int b = 2;

    if (x == 1) {
        std::cout << a << b;
    } else if (x > 1) {
        a = 2;
        b = 1;
        f(x - 1);
    }
}
```

[Live Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xhKTEdKzf)

Because `a` and `b` are `static` their value are shared between threads of execution. (ie: when you call the function again, `a` is `2` and `b` is `1`).

Comment: Yes,but this only work once.l mean, if l call f(3), it will use the variables set of f(2)(though they are the same in this case)

Comment: Well, I don't understand the question, then. What is the expected output? If you could provide unit tests I'll ne better able to help.

Comment: For example,If l change the content of the function like this:

Comment: void f(int){
static int a=1;
static int b=2;

if(x==1)
cout<<a<<b;
if(x==2){
a=2;
b=1;
f(x-1);}
if(x==3){
a=1;
b=2;
f(x-1);}
}

Comment: When l call f(3),the out put will be 21.But l want it to be 12.

Comment: I appreciate your help and sorry  for making the code hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

If the context is Towers of Hanoi, I guess that `a` and `b` are the numbers of towers (1, 2, or 3), and `x` represents the number of discs to move.

So for starters I would suggest using more descriptive variable names, like `fromTower`, `toTower`, `numDiscs`.

In your code the two assignments made just before the recursive call have no utility: as `a` and `b` are local variables, they don't play a role when `f` is called again. That new call of `f` will have its own `a` and `b` and it initialises them with the same values as in the initial call.

To make it work, define these variables as *parameters*. This is the way you pass desired values for certain variables to the next call of `f`.

Some other comments:

- Your code initialises `i`, but never uses it.
- When the recursive call returns, you are not done. Currently, your code would only reach the base case once, and only have one execution of `cout`. But you need more than that. After the recursive call returns, you should (also) make a move of one disc, and then make *another* recursive call to move the same `x-1` discs again.

Here is how a typical recursive implementation of Towers of Hanoi would look:

```
void hanoi_mover(int numDiscs, int fromTower, int toTower) {
    if (numDiscs == 0) return; // Base case: Nothing to do
    // Use recursion to move all-but-one disc to the "other" tower:
    hanoi_mover(numDiscs - 1, fromTower, fromTower ^ toTower);
    // Then move the remaining disc to the target tower:
    std::cout << fromTower << " to " << toTower << std::endl;
    // Finally, use recursion again to move the discs from step 1 
    //    from the "other" tower on top of this moved disc:
    hanoi_mover(numDiscs - 1, fromTower ^ toTower, toTower);
}
```

Here I have chosen to set the base case at `numDiscs == 0` instead of `numDiscs == 1`, as this allows to only have one `cout` in the program.

But the main takeaway is that the caller of `hanoi_mover` provides new values for the parameter variables `fromTower` and `toTower`, based on the values the caller has.

The more obscure part is the use of the `^`  (XOR) operator: it serves to derive the number of the "helper" tower that is neither `fromTower`, nor `toTower`, but the remaining one. This works if we number the towers 1, 2 and 3, because:

- `1 ^ 2 == 3`
- `1 ^ 3 == 2`
- `2 ^ 3 == 1`

If your Towers of Hanoi set up has four discs as its first tower and the task is to move them to the third tower, then the caller would call the above code like this:

```
    hanoi_mover(4, 1, 3); // Move 4 discs from tower #1 to tower #3
```

It will be convenient to have a function that only takes one argument and solves the problem assuming all discs are on the first tower and they need to move to the third. For that create a wrapper function whose only job is to call the above function with the extra arguments set to 1 and 3 (to indicate all discs are on tower #1 and need to move to tower #3):

```
void hanoi(int numDiscs) {
    hanoi_mover(numDiscs, 1, 3); // Provide the other two arguments
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what l want to do is using a function that have one variable which represents the number of discs ,and the towers being the variables.

Comment: After all, once the number of disc is determined, all steps of the game is unchangeable.

Comment: But that is trivial: just define a second function that only takes the number of discs as argument, and have it call the other function, providing it the initial values for the second and third argument.

Comment: See update in my answer to see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you.What do the second and third argument represent?

Comment: This is already explained in my answer: *"to indicate all discs are on tower #1 and need to move to tower #3"*. Also, you can see that these two arguments are assigned to parameters with the names `fromTower` and `toTower`.